# Remove rows with all or some NAs (missing values) in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, missing-data, r-faq

I'd like to remove the lines in this data frame that:

a) **contain `NA`s across all columns.** Below is my example data frame.

```
             gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
1 ENSG00000208234    0   NA   NA   NA   NA
2 ENSG00000199674    0   2    2    2    2
3 ENSG00000221622    0   NA   NA   NA   NA
4 ENSG00000207604    0   NA   NA   1    2
5 ENSG00000207431    0   NA   NA   NA   NA
6 ENSG00000221312    0   1    2    3    2
```

Basically, I'd like to get a data frame such as the following.

```
             gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
2 ENSG00000199674    0   2    2    2    2
6 ENSG00000221312    0   1    2    3    2
```

b) **contain `NA`s in only some columns**, so I can also get this result:

```
             gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
2 ENSG00000199674    0   2    2    2    2
4 ENSG00000207604    0   NA   NA   1    2
6 ENSG00000221312    0   1    2    3    2
```

Answer (score 1290, accepted):

Also check [`complete.cases`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/complete.cases.html) :

```
> final[complete.cases(final), ]
             gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
2 ENSG00000199674    0    2    2    2    2
6 ENSG00000221312    0    1    2    3    2
```

`na.omit` is nicer for just removing all `NA`'s. `complete.cases` allows partial selection by including only certain columns of the dataframe:

```
> final[complete.cases(final[ , 5:6]),]
             gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
2 ENSG00000199674    0    2    2    2    2
4 ENSG00000207604    0   NA   NA    1    2
6 ENSG00000221312    0    1    2    3    2
```

Your solution can't work. If you insist on using `is.na`, then you have to do something like:

```
> final[rowSums(is.na(final[ , 5:6])) == 0, ]
             gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
2 ENSG00000199674    0    2    2    2    2
4 ENSG00000207604    0   NA   NA    1    2
6 ENSG00000221312    0    1    2    3    2
```

but using `complete.cases` is quite a lot more clear, and faster.

Comment: What is the significance of the trailing comma in `final[complete.cases(final),]`?

Comment: the `complete.cases(final)` returns a boolean of rows where there are no `NA` like `(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)`. The trailing comma says all columns. Thus, before the comma you filter on the rows but after the comma you column you do no filtering and ask for everything

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I was not aware that we could specify columns with the ```complete.cases``` statement.

Comment: Notice that `na.omit` will remove rows which contains *at least* one NA (i.e., it is sufficient for one column to be NA for the row to be removed). Same for `complete.cases`: it returns FALSE if one (or more) of the columns you pass are NA

Answer (score 319):

Try `na.omit(your.data.frame)`. As for the second question, try posting it as another question (for clarity).

Answer (score 231):

`tidyr` has a new function [`drop_na`](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/08/15/tidyr-0-6-0/):

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% drop_na()
#              gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
# 2 ENSG00000199674    0    2    2    2    2
# 6 ENSG00000221312    0    1    2    3    2
df %>% drop_na(rnor, cfam)
#              gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
# 2 ENSG00000199674    0    2    2    2    2
# 4 ENSG00000207604    0   NA   NA    1    2
# 6 ENSG00000221312    0    1    2    3    2
```

Comment: What are the advantages of drop_na() over na.omit()?  Faster?

Comment: Notice this removes rows if one or more columns are NA (i.e., it is not necessary that *all* columns be NA)

Answer (score 105):

I prefer following way to check whether rows contain any NAs:

```
row.has.na <- apply(final, 1, function(x){any(is.na(x))})
```

This returns logical vector with values denoting whether there is any NA in a row. You can use it to see how many rows you'll have to drop:

```
sum(row.has.na)
```

and eventually drop them

```
final.filtered <- final[!row.has.na,]
```

For filtering rows with certain part of NAs it becomes a little trickier (for example, you can feed 'final[,5:6]' to 'apply').
Generally, Joris Meys' solution seems to be more elegant.

Comment: This is extremely slow. Much slower than e.g. the aforementioned complete.cases() solution. At least, in my case, on xts data.

Comment: `rowSum(!is.na(final))` seems better suited than `apply()`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `final[rowSum(is.na(final)),]`?

Answer (score 68):

If you want control over how many NAs are valid for each row, try this function. For many survey data sets, too many blank question responses can ruin the results. So they are deleted after a certain threshold. This function will allow you to choose how many NAs the row can have before it's deleted:

```
delete.na <- function(DF, n=0) {
  DF[rowSums(is.na(DF)) <= n,]
}
```

By default, it will eliminate all NAs:

```
delete.na(final)
             gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
2 ENSG00000199674    0    2    2    2    2
6 ENSG00000221312    0    1    2    3    2
```

Or specify the maximum number of NAs allowed:

```
delete.na(final, 2)
             gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
2 ENSG00000199674    0    2    2    2    2
4 ENSG00000207604    0   NA   NA    1    2
6 ENSG00000221312    0    1    2    3    2
```

Comment: This is the most reliable method to remove rows, when you need at least a number of NAs to remove that row. Helped me a lot!

Comment: Please see slightly faster version [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76749435/6574038). On this occasion, thanks very much for sharing this great solution, which I have been using ever since.

Answer (score 58):

#### If performance is a priority, use `data.table` and `na.omit()` with optional param `cols=`.

[`na.omit.data.table`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4-2/topics/na.omit.data.table) is the fastest on my benchmark (see below), whether for all columns or for select columns (OP question part 2).

#### If you don't want to use `data.table`, use `complete.cases()`.

On a vanilla `data.frame`, [`complete.cases`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.3/topics/complete.cases) is faster than [`na.omit()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.3/topics/na.fail) or [`dplyr::drop_na()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.0/topics/drop_na).  Notice that `na.omit.data.frame` does not support `cols=`.

#### Benchmark result

Here is a comparison of base (blue), `dplyr` (pink), and `data.table` (yellow) methods for dropping either all or select missing observations, on notional dataset of 1 million observations of 20 numeric variables with independent 5% likelihood of being missing, and a subset of 4 variables for part 2.

Your results may vary based on length, width, and sparsity of your particular dataset.

Note log scale on y axis.

[image]

#### Benchmark script

```
#-------  Adjust these assumptions for your own use case  ------------
row_size   <- 1e6L 
col_size   <- 20    # not including ID column
p_missing  <- 0.05   # likelihood of missing observation (except ID col)
col_subset <- 18:21  # second part of question: filter on select columns

#-------  System info for benchmark  ----------------------------------
R.version # R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30), platform = x86_64-w64-mingw32
library(data.table); packageVersion('data.table') # 1.10.4.3
library(dplyr);      packageVersion('dplyr')      # 0.7.4
library(tidyr);      packageVersion('tidyr')      # 0.8.0
library(microbenchmark)

#-------  Example dataset using above assumptions  --------------------
fakeData <- function(m, n, p){
  set.seed(123)
  m <-  matrix(runif(m*n), nrow=m, ncol=n)
  m[m<p] <- NA
  return(m)
}
df <- cbind( data.frame(id = paste0('ID',seq(row_size)), 
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
             data.frame(fakeData(row_size, col_size, p_missing) )
             )
dt <- data.table(df)

par(las=3, mfcol=c(1,2), mar=c(22,4,1,1)+0.1)
boxplot(
  microbenchmark(
    df[complete.cases(df), ],
    na.omit(df),
    df %>% drop_na,
    dt[complete.cases(dt), ],
    na.omit(dt)
  ), xlab='', 
  main = 'Performance: Drop any NA observation',
  col=c(rep('lightblue',2),'salmon',rep('beige',2))
)
boxplot(
  microbenchmark(
    df[complete.cases(df[,col_subset]), ],
    #na.omit(df), # col subset not supported in na.omit.data.frame
    df %>% drop_na(col_subset),
    dt[complete.cases(dt[,col_subset,with=FALSE]), ],
    na.omit(dt, cols=col_subset) # see ?na.omit.data.table
  ), xlab='', 
  main = 'Performance: Drop NA obs. in select cols',
  col=c('lightblue','salmon',rep('beige',2))
)
```

Answer (score 53):

Another option if you want greater control over how rows are deemed to be invalid is

```
final <- final[!(is.na(final$rnor)) | !(is.na(rawdata$cfam)),]
```

Using the above, this:

```
             gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
1 ENSG00000208234    0   NA   NA   NA   2
2 ENSG00000199674    0   2    2    2    2
3 ENSG00000221622    0   NA   NA   2   NA
4 ENSG00000207604    0   NA   NA   1    2
5 ENSG00000207431    0   NA   NA   NA   NA
6 ENSG00000221312    0   1    2    3    2
```

Becomes:

```
             gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
1 ENSG00000208234    0   NA   NA   NA   2
2 ENSG00000199674    0   2    2    2    2
3 ENSG00000221622    0   NA   NA   2   NA
4 ENSG00000207604    0   NA   NA   1    2
6 ENSG00000221312    0   1    2    3    2
```

...where only row 5 is removed since it is the only row containing NAs for both `rnor` AND `cfam`. The boolean logic can then be changed to fit specific requirements.

Comment: but how can you use this if you want to check many columns, without typing each one, can you use a range final[,4:100]?

Answer (score 23):

Using dplyr package we can filter NA as follows:

```
dplyr::filter(df,  !is.na(columnname))
```

Comment: This performs about 10.000 times slower than `drop_na()`

Comment: @Zimano Maybe true but for multiple variables `drop_na`  uses "any" logic and `filter` uses "all" logic. So if you need more flexiblity in expression, filter has more possibilities.

Comment: @jiggunjer That's absolutely true! It really depends on what you're trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 20):

This will return the rows that have at least ONE non-NA value.

```
final[rowSums(is.na(final))<length(final),]
```

This will return the rows that have at least TWO non-NA value.

```
final[rowSums(is.na(final))<(length(final)-1),]
```

Comment: This is perfect, I was actually looking for a similar solution that could allow us to keep only those rows (irrespective of the columns) that have one or more non-NA values.

However, this code is not working in my case. It retains all rows, even those that have all NAs.

Answer (score 20):

One approach that's both general and yields fairly-readable code is to use the `filter()` function and the `across()` helper functions from the {dplyr} package.

```
library(dplyr)

vars_to_check <- c("rnor", "cfam")

# Filter a specific list of columns to keep only non-missing entries

df %>% 
  filter(across(one_of(vars_to_check),
                ~ !is.na(.x)))

# Filter all the columns to exclude NA
df %>% 
  filter(across(everything(),
                ~ !is.na(.)))

# Filter only numeric columns
df %>%
  filter(across(where(is.numeric),
                ~ !is.na(.)))
```

Similarly, there are also the variant functions in the dplyr package (`filter_all`, `filter_at`, `filter_if`) which accomplish the same thing:

```
library(dplyr)

vars_to_check <- c("rnor", "cfam")

# Filter a specific list of columns to keep only non-missing entries
df %>% 
  filter_at(.vars = vars(one_of(vars_to_check)),
            ~ !is.na(.))

# Filter all the columns to exclude NA
df %>% 
  filter_all(~ !is.na(.))

# Filter only numeric columns
df %>%
  filter_if(is.numeric,
            ~ !is.na(.))
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62829853/4627134)  for another example using `across`

Answer (score 19):

For your first question, I have a code that I am comfortable with to get rid of all NAs. Thanks for @Gregor to make it simpler.

```
final[!(rowSums(is.na(final))),]
```

For the second question, the code is just an alternation from the previous solution.

```
final[as.logical((rowSums(is.na(final))-5)),]
```

Notice the -5 is the number of columns in your data. This will eliminate rows with all NAs, since the rowSums adds up to 5 and they become zeroes after subtraction. This time, as.logical is necessary.

Comment: final[as.logical((rowSums(is.na(final))-ncol(final))),]  for a universal answer

Answer (score 14):

We can also use the subset function for this.

```
finalData<-subset(data,!(is.na(data["mmul"]) | is.na(data["rnor"])))
```

This will give only those rows that do not have NA in both mmul and rnor

Answer (score 13):

[dplyr](https://www.tidyverse.org/tags/dplyr/) 1.0.4 introduced two companion functions to `filter`: they are `if_any()` and `if_all()`. The `if_all()` companion function will be particularly useful in this case:

**a) To remove rows that contain NAs across all columns**

```
df %>% 
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ !is.na(.x)))
```

This line will keep only those rows where none of the columns have NAs.

**b) To remove rows that contain NAs in only some columns**

```
cols_to_check = c("rnor", "cfam")

df %>% 
  filter(if_all(cols_to_check, ~ !is.na(.x)))
```

This line will check if any of the specified columns (cols_to_check) have NAs, and only keep those rows where this is not the case.

Comment: If rows with at least one NA value needs to be removed, one can try `df %>% filter(if_any(everything(), ~!is.na(.x)))` or `na.omit(df)`.

Comment: which solution takes less time, the one you suggested or this one:

df %>%
    filter(!if_all(everything(), ~  is.na(.)))

Answer (score 10):

Assuming `dat` as your dataframe, the expected output can be achieved using

1.`rowSums`

```
> dat[!rowSums((is.na(dat))),]
             gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
2 ENSG00000199674    0   2    2    2    2
6 ENSG00000221312    0   1    2    3    2
```

2.`lapply`

```
> dat[!Reduce('|',lapply(dat,is.na)),]
             gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
2 ENSG00000199674    0   2    2    2    2
6 ENSG00000221312    0   1    2    3    2
```

Answer (score 9):

I am a synthesizer:). Here I combined the answers into one function:

```
#' keep rows that have a certain number (range) of NAs anywhere/somewhere and delete others
#' @param df a data frame
#' @param col restrict to the columns where you would like to search for NA; eg, 3, c(3), 2:5, "place", c("place","age")
#' \cr default is NULL, search for all columns
#' @param n integer or vector, 0, c(3,5), number/range of NAs allowed.
#' \cr If a number, the exact number of NAs kept
#' \cr Range includes both ends 3<=n<=5
#' \cr Range could be -Inf, Inf
#' @return returns a new df with rows that have NA(s) removed
#' @export
ez.na.keep = function(df, col=NULL, n=0){
    if (!is.null(col)) {
        # R converts a single row/col to a vector if the parameter col has only one col
        # see https://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/design-flaws-in-r-2-%E2%80%94-dropped-dimensions/#comments
        df.temp = df[,col,drop=FALSE]
    } else {
        df.temp = df
    }

    if (length(n)==1){
        if (n==0) {
            # simply call complete.cases which might be faster
            result = df[complete.cases(df.temp),]
        } else {
            # credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30461945/2292993
            log <- apply(df.temp, 2, is.na)
            logindex <- apply(log, 1, function(x) sum(x) == n)
            result = df[logindex, ]
        }
    }

    if (length(n)==2){
        min = n[1]; max = n[2]
        log <- apply(df.temp, 2, is.na)
        logindex <- apply(log, 1, function(x) {sum(x) >= min && sum(x) <= max})
        result = df[logindex, ]
    }

    return(result)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
delete.dirt <- function(DF, dart=c('NA')) {
  dirty_rows <- apply(DF, 1, function(r) !any(r %in% dart))
  DF <- DF[dirty_rows, ]
}

mydata <- delete.dirt(mydata)
```

Above function deletes all the rows from the data frame that has 'NA' in any column and returns the resultant data. If you want to check for multiple values like `NA` and `?` change `dart=c('NA')` in function param to `dart=c('NA', '?')`

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that this could be more elegantly solved in this way:

```
  m <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5)
  m[c(1, 6, 13, 25)] <- NA
  df <- data.frame(m)
  library(dplyr) 
  df %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(is.na(.)))
  #>   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
  #> 1 NA NA 11 16 21
  #> 2  3  8 NA 18 23
  #> 3  5 10 15 20 NA
```

Comment: this will retain rows with `NA`. I think what the OP wants is:
`df %>% filter_all(all_vars(!is.na(.)))`

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to remove only the rows having NAs in all columns, here is the solution:

```
df %>%
    filter(!if_all(everything(), ~  is.na(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the `na_omit` function of `collapse`:

```r
na_omit(df)
#              gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
# 1 ENSG00000199674    0    2    2    2    2
# 2 ENSG00000221312    0    1    2    3    2
```

Or, for selected columns:

```r
na_omit(df, cols = c("rnor", "cfam")) #Alternatively, works with a function, index or logical vector

#              gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
# 1 ENSG00000199674    0    2    2    2    2
# 2 ENSG00000207604    0   NA   NA    1    2
# 3 ENSG00000221312    0    1    2    3    2
```

---

`collapse::na_omit` is faster than any other solutions provided here, including `data.table::na.omit` and `tidyr::drop_na`:

```r
#Using data from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48830183/13460602
mb <- 
  microbenchmark(
  collapse = na_omit(dt),
  dt = na.omit(dt), 
  base = na.omit(df),
  complete.cases = df[complete.cases(df), ],
  tidyr = drop_na(df)
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#            expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval
#        collapse  70.6927 130.5431 191.9058 156.6320  217.1957  915.6074   100
#              dt  76.5151 130.7049 195.9737 172.6981  215.2754  735.1839   100
#            base 406.3456 778.5028 900.1791 860.7407 1005.6444 2009.2036   100
#  complete.cases 295.6927 497.8572 649.3397 575.9408  715.9452 2137.3366   100
#           tidyr  83.4586 145.3758 207.3149 180.9264  242.0750  838.3654   100
```

Answer (score 0):

For **removing rows with *some* missings,** i.e. where the columns are not known beforehand, we have [@PierreL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30461945/6574038)'s great answer using `rowSums()`.

I would like to quickly point out a slightly faster way using `rowSums2` from the [matrixStats](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/matrixStats/index.html) package. For a 200,000x1,000 matrix, this saves almost a second.

The function is applied in the same way. (Note, that the result of `is.na()` is already of class `"matrix"`, otherwise `rowSums2` would have complained.)

```
M[matrixStats::rowSums2(is.na(M)) < dim(M)[2]*1e-2, ]  ## allow 1% missings per row
```

#### Benchmark

```
Unit: seconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  rowSums 3.083927 3.104315 3.135399 3.131235 3.162080 3.209985   100
 rowSums2 2.129368 2.241577 2.347562 2.287717 2.494494 2.683859   100
```

[image]

***Code:***

```
m=2e5; n=1e3
set.seed(42)
M <- matrix(rpois(n*m, 2), m, n)
M[sample(seq_along(M), m*n*.01)] <- NA_integer_

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rowSums=M[rowSums(is.na(M)) < dim(M)[2]*1e-2, ],
  rowSums2=M[matrixStats::rowSums2(is.na(M)) < dim(M)[2]*1e-2, ],
  check='identical'
  ) |> print()

Rscript --vanilla ~/is_na_issue.R
```