# how to get rid of NaN value in R

Tags: r, nan

I have a variable in R. I am going to do PCA analysis. but I have a lot of NaN values. do you guys know how to get rid of them?

my data looks like this:

```
        11819 11820 11821      
s1  1.1547005 NaN  1.1547005 
s2 -0.5773503 NaN -0.5773503 
s4 -0.5773503 NaN -0.5773503
```

11819, 11820 and 11821 are col names and s1, s2 and s4 are row names.
thanks

Comment: Is the whole column NaN?

Comment: yes the whole column is NaN

Comment: Appearance of NaNs in results is often indicative of a mistake on practitioner’s part. So before removing then, you better know where they came from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove row with nan value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961839/remove-row-with-nan-value) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773189/remove-na-nan-inf-in-a-matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try

```
na.omit(your.data.frame)
```

EDIT:

If you want to remove the entire column you can try

```
data[,the.number.of.the.column.with.NA] <- NULL  or
data$the.name.of.the.column.with.NA <- NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[, colSums(is.na(df)) != nrow(df)]
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968494/how-to-delete-columns-that-contain-only-nas)

Answer (score 0):

to remove columns containing Na's or NaN's you can use this:

```
df <-  df[ , apply(df, MARGIN = 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) == 0)]
```