# How to remove "rows" with a NA value?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R - remove rows with NAs in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/r-remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame)

How can I quickly remove "rows" in a dataframe with a NA value in one of the columns?

So

```
     x1  x2
[1,]  1 100
[2,]  2  NA
[3,]  3 300
[4,] NA 400
[5,]  5 500
```

should result in:

```
     x1  x2
[1,]  1 100
[3,]  3 300
[5,]  5 500
```

Comment: See the answers there for a solution to your problem. And be aware that you show us a matrix and not a dataframe.

Comment: Please at least *attempt* to search for your answer here (adding `[r]` to search within R questions), via Rseek.org or otherwise.

Comment: Isn't that question concerned with ALL values in the row being NA's? and possibly NA's in specific columns? As such this is a slightly different (and easier) question. As is usual with easy and hard applications of the same concept, one can infer the easy answer from the hard, but that may be hard :)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3, NA, 5), x2 = c(100, NA, 300, 400, 500))

na.omit(dat)
  x1  x2
1  1 100
3  3 300
5  5 500
```

Comment: In my case, this is not working! 
`df<-structure(list(vars = structure(1:5, .Label = c("a", "b", 
                                                "v", "d", "e", "s", "ds"
), class = "factor"), '1' = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                              NA_real_), '2' = c(NA, 0.9, NA, NA, NA), '3' = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
          NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("vars", "1", "2", 
 "3"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")`