# Removing specific rows with some NA values in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to remove rows from a data frame where a column has NA only if the other rows where the NA value is found matches others value in the data frame

For example,

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2),DAY=c(1,1,2,3), VAL=c(1,NA,NA,5))
```

I want to remove the second row because there is a missing value in VAL and there is already a value for VAL with ID = 1 and DAY = 1 to get

```
ID      DAY     VAL
1        1        1
2        2        NA
2        3        5
```

Any idea how to do this? I could try writing a loop, but that doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove "rows" with a NA value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138776/how-to-remove-rows-with-a-na-value)

Comment: @MichaelChirico  I didn't find it as a duplicate because `na.omit` is more general and it omits all the rows with the `NA` values.  But, here the OP wants to remove NA values selectively by group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done by creating a logical condition within each grouping variable.  Here, I am guessing 'ID' and 'DAY' as the grouping variable.

One option is using `data.table`. We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`).  Grouped by 'ID', 'DAY', we get the row index (`.I`) of 'VAL' that satisfy the condition (`sum(is.na(VAL))!= .N & is.na(VAL)`) and remove the that row index from the dataset 'df'.  The `sum(is.na(VAL))!= .N` gives a logical vector that checks whether the number of `NA` values in a group is not equal to number of rows in that group (`.N`).  If the 'VAL' is also an 'NA' along with the previous condition, then that is removed.

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[, .I[sum(is.na(VAL))!=.N & is.na(VAL)] , by = .(ID, DAY)]$V1
df[-i1]
#   ID DAY VAL
#1:  1   1   1
#2:  2   2  NA
#3:  2   3   5
```

Or a similar option with `dplyr`.  We group by 'ID', DAY', and then use `filter` with the above mentioned condition.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID, DAY) %>% 
   filter(!(sum(is.na(VAL))!=n() & is.na(VAL)))
#  ID DAY VAL
#1  1   1   1
#2  2   2  NA
#3  2   3   5
```

Comment: Maybe I am not reading carefully enough but, why are the two solutions returning different results?

Comment: @mplanco Because there is a small error in the `dplyr` code. It should read: `df %>% group_by(ID, DAY) %>% filter(!(sum(is.na(VAL))!=n() & is.na(VAL)))`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré  Thanks, I was trying something different and got a different result.

Comment: @mpalanco Thanks for your comment.  I didn't even notice it.