# Removing empty rows of a data file in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with empty rows. I would like to remove them:

```
myData<-myData[-which(apply(myData,1,function(x)all(is.na(x)))),]
```

It works OK. But now I would like to add a column in my data and initialize the first value:

```
myData$newCol[1] <- -999

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "newCol", value = -999) : 
  replacement has 1 rows, data has 0
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I don't really understand why and I can't solve this.
It worked when I removed one line at a time using:

```
TgData = TgData[2:nrow(TgData),]
```

Or anything similar.

It also works when I used only the first 13.000 rows.

But it doesn't work with my actual data, with 32.000 rows.

What did I do wrong? It seems to make no sense to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove rows with NAs in data.frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I assume you want to remove rows that are all NAs. Then, you can do the following :

```
data <- rbind(c(1,2,3), c(1, NA, 4), c(4,6,7), c(NA, NA, NA), c(4, 8, NA)) # sample data
data
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1   NA    4
[3,]    4    6    7
[4,]   NA   NA   NA
[5,]    4    8   NA

data[rowSums(is.na(data)) != ncol(data),]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1   NA    4
[3,]    4    6    7
[4,]    4    8   NA
```

If you want to remove rows that have at least one NA, just change the condition :

```
data[rowSums(is.na(data)) == 0,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    6    7
```

Comment: The second case can also be handled via: `data[complete.cases(data),]`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thx for your helping answer! Just for the understanding? Why do you let a `,` in the end of `data[complete.cases(data),]` your code?

Comment: @mrquad, that means you're subsetting by rows; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17052459/2152245.

Comment: This solution works great, but I didn't understand it at first ... for anyone who's struggling like I did, what this code is doing is simply counting the fields in each row that have NA in them, and then comparing that count to the total count of columns in the dataframe.  If the two are equal, that's the row you want deleted.

Answer (score 75):

If you have empty rows, not NAs, you can do:

```
data[!apply(data == "", 1, all),]
```

To remove both (NAs and empty):

```
data <- data[!apply(is.na(data) | data == "", 1, all),]
```

Comment: This is so elegant. It worked for me when I needed the most. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Here are some `dplyr` options:

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(a = c('1', NA, '3', NA), b = c('a', 'b', 'c', NA), c = c('e', 'f', 'g', NA))

library(dplyr)

# remove rows where all values are NA:
df %>% filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.)))
df %>% filter_all(any_vars(complete.cases(.)))  


# remove rows where only some values are NA:
df %>% filter_all(all_vars(!is.na(.)))
df %>% filter_all(all_vars(complete.cases(.)))  

# or more succinctly:
df %>% filter(complete.cases(.))  
df %>% na.omit

# dplyr and tidyr:
library(tidyr)
df %>% drop_na
```

Comment: Neither na.omit() nor drop_na() return non-NA rows.

Answer (score 20):

Alternative solution for rows of `NA`s using [`janitor`](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor) package

```
myData %>% remove_empty("rows")
```

Comment: This was the simplest solution and it worked for me -- thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`'s `if_all`/`if_any`

Drop rows with any `NA` OR Select rows with no `NA` value.

```
df %>% filter(!if_any(a:c, is.na))

#  a b c
#1 1 a e
#2 3 c g

#Also
df %>% filter(if_all(a:c, Negate(is.na)))
```

Drop rows with all `NA` values or select rows with at least one non-NA value.

```
df %>% filter(!if_all(a:c, is.na))

#     a b c
#1    1 a e
#2 <NA> b f
#3    3 c g

#Also
df %>% filter(if_any(a:c, Negate(is.na)))
```

**data**

Using data from @sbha -

```
df <- data.frame(a = c('1', NA, '3', NA), 
                 b = c('a', 'b', 'c', NA), 
                 c = c('e', 'f', 'g', NA))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to some of the above answers, but with this, you can specify if you want to remove rows with a percentage of missing values greater-than or equal-to a given percent (with the argument `pct`)

```
drop_rows_all_na <- function(x, pct=1) x[!rowSums(is.na(x)) >= ncol(x)*pct,]
```

Where `x` is a dataframe and `pct` is the threshold of `NA`-filled data you want to get rid of.

`pct = 1` means remove rows that have 100% of its values `NA`.
`pct = .5` means remome rows that have at least half its values `NA`

Comment: How to use this FUN on df?

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another answer if you just want a handy function wrapper. Also, many of the above solutions remove a row with ANY NAs, whereas this one only removes rows that are ALL NAs.

```
data <- rbind(c(1,2,3), c(1, NA, 4), c(4,6,7), c(NA, NA, NA), c(4, 8, NA)) # sample data
data

rmNArows<-function(d){
goodRows<-apply(d,1,function(x) sum(is.na(x))!=ncol(d))
d[goodRows,]
}

rmNArows(data)
```