# Why does item assignment in non-existant data.frame column work?

Tags: r

Inspired by [Q6437164](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437164/removing-empty-rows-of-a-data-file-in-r): can someone explain to me why the following works:

```
iriscopy<-iris #or whatever other data.frame
iriscopy$someNonExistantColumn[1]<-15
```

To me, it seems not obvious how R interprets this statement as: create a new column with name `someNonExistantColumn` in the data.frame, and set the first value (in fact, all values, as it seems) to the value 15.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The R language definition manual gives us a pointer to how R evaluates expressions of the form:

```
x$foo[1] <- 15
```

namely it is as if we have called

```
`*tmp*` <- x
x <- "$<-.data.frame"(`*tmp*`, name = "foo", 
                      value = "[<-.data.frame"("$.data.frame"(`*tmp*`, "foo"), 
                                               1, value = 15))
rm(`*tmp*`)
```

the middle bit might be easier to grapple with if we drop, for purposes of exposition, the actual methods used:

```
x <- "$<-"(`*tmp*`, name = "foo", 
           value = "[<-"("$"(`*tmp*`, "foo"), 1, value = 15))
```

To go back to your example using `iris`, we have something like

```
iris$foo[1] <- 15
```

Here, the functions are evaluated recursively. First the extractor function `"$"` is used to access component `"foo"` from `iris`, which is `NULL`:

```
> "$"(iris, "foo")
NULL
```

Then, `"[<-"` is used to replace the first element of the object returned above (the `NULL`) with the value `15`, i.e. a call of:

```
> "[<-"(NULL, 1, value = 15)
[1] 15
```

Now, this is the object that is used as argument `value` in the outermost part of our call, namely the assignment using `"$<-"`:

```
> head("$<-"(iris, "foo", value = 15))
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species foo
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa  15
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa  15
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa  15
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa  15
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  15
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa  15
```

(here wrapped in `head()` to limit the number of rows shown.)

That hopefully explains how the function calls progress. The last issue to deal with is why the entire vector `foo` is set to 15? The answer to that is given in the Details section of `?"$<-.data.frame"`:

```
Details:

....

         Note that there is no ‘data.frame’ method for ‘$’, so ‘x$name’
     uses the default method which treats ‘x’ as a list.  There is a
     replacement method which checks ‘value’ for the correct number of
     rows, and replicates it if necessary.
```

The key bit is the last sentence. In the above example, the outermost assignment used `value = 15`. But at this point, we are wanting to replace the *entire* component `"foo"`, which is of length `nrow(iris)`. Hence, what is actually used is `value = rep(15, nrow(iris))`, in the outermost assignment/function call.

This example is all the more complex because you have to convert from the convenience notation of

```
x$foo[1] <- 15
```

into proper function calls using `"$<-"()`, `"[<-"()`, and `"$"()`. The example in [Section 3.4.4](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/doc/manual/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment) of The R Language Definition uses this simpler example:

```
names(x)[3] <- "Three"
```

which evaluates to

```
`*tmp*` <- x
x <- "names<-"(`*tmp*`, value="[<-"(names(`*tmp*`), 3, value="Three"))
rm(`*tmp*`)
```

which is slightly easier to get your head around because `names()` looks like a usual function call.

Comment: That is just wicked beautiful. I'm glad I asked and I'm glad you answered. You just saved me from mental illness.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is that it doesn't work.

I consider the `$newcol` to be standard behaviour to create a new column.  For example:

```
iris$newcol <- 1
```

will create a new column in the iris data.frame.  All values will be 1, because of vector recycling.

This creation of a new column gets triggered when the expression evaluates to NULL.  From ?`$<-`:

- *"When $<- is applied to a NULL x, it first coerces x to list(). This is what also happens with [[<- if the replacement value value is of length greater than one: if value has length 1 or 0, x is first coerced to a zero-length vector of the type of value."*

So I think what happens here is that the expression evaluates to NULL, and this triggers the code to create a new column, which in turn uses vector recycling to fill the values.

**Edit**

The parsing probably works using $-assign `$<-` rather than bracket-assign `[<-`.  Compare:

```
head(`$<-`(iris, newcol, 1))
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species newcol
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa      1
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa      1
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa      1
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa      1
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa      1
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa      1
```

But bracket assign produces an error:

```
head(`[<-`(iris, newcol, 1))
Error in head(`[<-`(iris, newcol, 1)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'head': Error in is.atomic(value) : 'value' is missing
```

Comment: Actually, I don't really get how this (my original code) is parsed in R. Is it `bracketassign(dollar(iriscopy, someNonExistantColumn), 1, 15)`? Or is it `dollarassign(iriscopy, bracket(someNonExistantColumn, 1), 15)`? (excuse the silly naming here). Or am I falsely assuming that everything is eventually parsed as a function call?

Comment: @NickSabbe I am going well beyond my comfort zone here, but I tried to answer your question in my edit.

Comment: I don't think you are calling `[<-` right there. Look at `args('[<-.data.frame')` and you'll see you need to specify `i`, `j` and `value`, and `i` or `j` can be blank, just as you would leave them blank in extraction. So `head('[<-'(iris, , 6, 2))` works, but you can't name the column as it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Gavin: can you provide some input on my original question? I'm driving myself crazy here in trying to interpret how `iriscopy$someNonExistantColumn[1]<-15` is parsed by R. @Andrie had some ideas on the what, but not really (yet) on the why.

Comment: @Nick Sabbe see my answer just submitted. This makes my brain hurt, but I think I have got to the bottom of it. It is hard so took a while getting the explanation right.