# Remove rows in R matrix where all data is NA

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing empty rows of a data file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437164/removing-empty-rows-of-a-data-file-in-r)

How would I remove rows from a matrix or data frame where *all* elements in the row are NA?

So to get from this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   11
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    3    8   13
[4,]    4   NA   NA
[5,]    5   10   NA
```

to this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   11
[2,]    3    8   13
[3,]    4   NA   NA
[4,]    5   10   NA
```

Because the problem with na.omit is that it removes rows with *any* NAs and so would give me this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   11
[2,]    3    8   13
```

The best I have been able to do so far is use the apply() function:

```
> x[apply(x, 1, function(y) !all(is.na(y))),]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   11
[2,]    3    8   13
[3,]    4   NA   NA
[4,]    5   10   NA
```

but this seems quite convoluted (is there something simpler that I am missing?)....

Thanks.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Solutions using rowSums() generally outperform apply() ones:

```
m <- structure(c( 1,  NA,  3,  4,  5, 
                  6,  NA,  8, NA, 10, 
                 11,  NA, 13, NA, NA), 
               .Dim = c(5L, 3L))

m[rowSums(is.na(m)) != ncol(m), ]

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   11
[2,]    3    8   13
[3,]    4   NA   NA
[4,]    5   10   NA
```

Comment: This is the same solution as the linked question, except the number of columns is hard-coded.

Comment: I see that you are right. Will vote to close.

Answer (score 47):

Sweep a test for  `all(is.na())` across rows, and remove where true. Something like this (untested as you provided no code to generate your data -- `dput()` is your friend):

```
 R> ind <- apply(X, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))
 R> X <- X[ !ind, ]
```

Comment: maybe slower but I like it because it expresses the logic better

Comment: This option works with non-numeric data too. but the apply solution in the linked questions avoids the index and does it in one line.