# Select rows from a data frame where any variable is not NA

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing empty rows of a data file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437164/removing-empty-rows-of-a-data-file-in-r)

Suppose I have a dataframe `df`

I would like to select the rows from it, where any of the variables in the row are not `NA`. That is to say I only want to exclude the rows in which **all** the variables are `NA`

Comment: OK thanks - I found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471689/remove-rows-in-r-matrix-where-all-data-is-na

Comment: Joe, I've been meaning to check out the `mice` package, but there's another package called `mix` that implements some MI methods, too. I recall from a bunch of years ago when I was using that package that there's a function called `prelim.mix` that provides a lot of good information on the missingness of your variables.

Answer (score 13):

```
df[apply(!is.na(df), 1, any), ]
```