# How to remove rows with all NA values for a group of columns in my dataset using R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

My dataset (df1) has 340 rows with 55 columns. If I need to filter out and remove rows which contain all NAs in column 10 - 55, how do I achieve this using R.

I tried the following code:

```
df2 <- df1[!is.na(c(df1$x10:df1$x55))]
```

but it shows an error stating:

```
Error in df1$x10:df1$x55 : 
  NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In df1$x10:df1$x55 :
  numerical expression has 340 elements: only the first used
2: In df1$x10:df1$x55 :
  numerical expression has 340 elements: only the first used
```

Comment: Do you mean "I need to filter out and remove rows which contain *only* NAs in column 10-55" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove rows where all variables are NA using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609912/remove-rows-where-all-variables-are-na-using-dplyr) - `df1 %>% filter(if_any(10:55, ~ !is.na(.)))` should work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in base R. Basically, you first generate the row indices and then filter. To generate the row indices, you check for every row of the data.frame with the respective columns if `all` values are `NA`.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  x1 = 1:3,
  x2 = c(1, NA, NA),
  x3 = c(1, 2, NA)
)

col_names <- paste0("x", 2:3)
row_indices <- apply(df1[, col_names], 1, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))

df1[row_indices, ]
#>   x1 x2 x3
#> 1  1  1  1
#> 2  2 NA  2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>