# Why is the function work after doing fix() in R

Tags: r

Here's what had happened:

```
> NA.of.df = which(rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df))
> NA.of.df 
named integer(0)
> fix(df) # i want to see what's in here -- nothing wrong
> NA.of.df # so i run it again  
1 3 5 7 9 # it works!
```

why would this happens??

A producible example (but doesn't seems like any data structure with `dput()`) is like the following:

```
> dput(NA.of.df)
structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0))
```

and `NA.of.df` is just the code for finding rows with all NAs (obtained from here:
[Remove rows in R matrix where all data is NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471689/remove-rows-in-r-matrix-where-all-data-is-na)). (i.e. `NA.of.df = which(rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df))`)

Comment: What is `df` here

Comment: @akrun df is a >10,000 rows df, I will see if I can make a toy data; however, do you know why this happens?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce with `NA.of.df <- which(rowSums(is.na(head(mtcars))) == ncol(mtcars))`

Comment: Can you try on a fresh R session.  May be some of the NA have quotes around it and after the `fix`, it may have evaluated to remove those quotes?

Comment: @akrun OHHHH!!! That's it! Thanks! Do you want to submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be an issue with quotes around the `NA` resulting in `is.na` to not pick up those elements

```
is.na(c(NA, "NA"))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

After doing the `fix`, it may have dropped the quotes and evaluate it correctly