# Removing NA with dplyr::filter()

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, na

The data is like

```
example<-matrix(NA,40,7)
colnames(example)=c("1month","2month","3month","4month","5month","6month","7month")
example[,1]<-rep(c(1,3,6,2,4,98,5,3,NA),len=40)
example[,2]<-rep(c(2,7,NA,8,2,NA,3,NA),len=40)
example[,3]<-rep(c(5,3,2,NA),len=40)
example[,4]<-rep(c(NA,91,98,52,35,NA),len=40)
example[,5]<-rep(c(3,NA),len=40)
example[,6]<-rep(c(98,NA,NA,123),len=40)
example[,7]<-rep(c(3,51,NA,NA,4,NA,5,NA),len=40)
example<-as.data.frame(example)
```

I want to remove 'NA' for each column.

I can do it using `drop_na` function

but `!is.na()` doesn't work.

`example %>% select('1month') %>% drop_na('1month')`<- this work

`example %>% select('1month') %>% filter(!is.na('1month'))` <- this doesn't work. the result for this is under.

I wonder why this doesn't work and there is any way that I can use `!=` or `!is.na()` function.

Thank you for your help. Sincerely.

```
   1month
1       1
2       3
3       6
4       2
5       4
6      98
7       5
8       3
9      NA
10      1
11      3
12      6
13      2
14      4
15     98
16      5
17      3
18     NA
19      1
20      3
21      6
22      2
23      4
24     98
25      5
26      3
27     NA
28      1
29      3
30      6
31      2
32      4
33     98
34      5
35      3
36     NA
37      1
38      3
39      6
40      2
```

Comment: `example %>% filter(!is.na(\`1month\`))`

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks, then what if I want to remove all NA from several columns??
like, want to remove NA from '1month' and '2month' at the same time.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471689/remove-rows-in-r-matrix-where-all-data-is-na