# What is the purpose of this trailing comma in R?

Tags: r

Why does the first line work and the 2nd not? I can't find the reason in the documentation on how to use which to select data although by chance I figured out I needed a comma.

```
sigData <- data[which(abs(data$wc2) > 3*wc2_sd),]


sigData <- data[which(abs(data$wc2) > 3*wc2_sd)]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The trailing comma in the first line indicates you're subsetting by rows (remember `[` is a function that means subset)

The lack of a trailing comma in the second line indicates you're subsetting by columns.  The second row would be equivalent to using a leading comma inside the brackets.

```
sigData <- data[, which(abs(data$wc2) > 3*wc2_sd)]
```

Comment: Only if you're operating on a data frame. Generally subsetting without a comma means you're indexing the data as a flat vector: 
i.e. `m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2, 2); m[3]` will give you the 3rd element as if the matrix is a vector

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct, even in the context of a DataFrame. See:
`test = data.frame(matrix(seq1:6),2) 
>>> typeof(test[c(1)])
[1] "list"
>>> typeof(test[,c(1)])
[1] "integer"`

Comment: Would the following mnemonic device be safe then, "assume that the dataframe subsetting works as grids of dataframename[row, column] ?"