# Delete only an entire row with NA, in R

Tags: r, rows, delete-row, na

I have something like this in my dataset and I only want to delete a row if it only has NA's, not if it has at least one value.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1   NA    4
[3,]    4    6    7
[4,]   NA   NA   NA
[5,]    4    8   NA
```

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437164/removing-empty-rows-of-a-data-file-in-r) they were able to delete what i want, but when i try to do in the exact same way, it doesn't work.

I've already tried their example:

> data[rowSums(is.na(data)) != ncol(data),]

But my row's number don't change like this one.

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1   NA    4
[3,]    4    6    7
[4,]    4    8   NA
```

My NA's are not characters.if i ask for their class:

```
class(NA)
[1] "logical"
```

Do you know another way to ask for these, please?

______UPDATE_____

Maybe I said it wrong.

My problem, and it's why there code is not working

```
mymat[rowSums(is.na(mymat)) != ncol(mymat), ]
```

Because i have 3 columns with information but after that, is everything NA, like this:

```
Date         Product    Code   protein   fat
2016-01-01     aaa      0001      NA     NA
2016-01-01     bbb      0003      NA     NA
2016-02-01     ccc      0032      NA     NA
```

So the row is not entirly NA's, only after the 3rd column... But i want to remove the entire row.. (1:5)

Thank you!

Comment: You don't have row numbers there.  Please check the dimnames

Answer (score 1):

Check if this will work with the updated explanation.  It will subset the `data.frame` to ignore the information columns when checking for `NA`.  I added some additional rows that contain a mix of numbers and `NA`

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date=c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-03-01"),
              Product=c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"),
              Code=c("0001", "0003", "0032", "0005", "0007"),
              protein=c(NA, NA, NA, 5, NA),
              fat=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4))

# place any columns you do not want to check for NA in names.info
names.info <- c("Date", "Product", "Code")
names.check <- setdiff(names(df1), names.info)

df1[rowSums(is.na(df1[, names.check])) != length(names.check), ]

        Date Product Code protein fat
4 2016-03-01     ddd 0005       5  NA
5 2016-03-01     eee 0007      NA   4
```

Comment: thank you for your help, however i think i didn't explain me very well.. now I updated my question, can you help me please?

Comment: @AnaRaquel see updated answer as this will ignore the information columns and will work regardless of the number of data columns used

Answer (score 1):

First, I would coerce the matrix to a data frame, because this is the typical ("tidy") format to store variables and observations. Then you could use the `remove_empty_rows()` function from the [sjmisc-package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjmisc):

library(sjmisc)

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 1, 4, NA, 4),
  b = c(2, NA, 6, NA, 8),
  c = c(3, 4, 7, NA, NA)
)

# get row numbers of empty rows
empty_rows(df)

## [1] 4

# remove empty rows
remove_empty_rows(df)

##  A tibble: 4 × 3
##        a     b     c
##  * <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
##  1     1     2     3
##  2     1    NA     4
##  3     4     6     7
##  4     4     8    NA
```

There are also functions for columns: `empty_cols()` and `remove_empty_cols()`.

If you just want to keep complete cases (rows), use `complete.cases()`:

```
df[complete.cases(df), ]

##   a b c
## 1 1 2 3
## 3 4 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the as.integer

```
mymat <- matrix(c(1:3, NA, 4:6, NA, rep(NA, 4)), ncol = 3)
```

Which translates to

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4   NA
[2,]    2    5   NA
[3,]    3    6   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA


mymat[as.integer(rowSums(is.na(mymat)) != ncol(mymat)), ]
```

Gives you

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4   NA
[2,]    1    4   NA
[3,]    1    4   NA
```

But you want

```
mymat[rowSums(is.na(mymat)) != ncol(mymat), ]
```

To get

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4   NA
[2,]    2    5   NA
[3,]    3    6   NA
```

Cheers,
Marc

Comment: thank you for your help, however i think i didn't explain me very well.. now I updated my question, can you help me please?

Comment: Do I you right that you want to delete the columns and not the rows?

Comment: I did it other way around, but thank you anyways! :)