# Exchange NA's in a matrix with a single default value if row is "empty"

Tags: r, matrix, na

I have a huge matrix with multiple columns and rows.
It contains numeric values and NAs.

Here is my problem:
I have some rows only consisting of NAs meaning they are basically empty.
These rows interfere with my further calculations but I also can not just delete them.

Now to my question:

Is there a quick function I can use on my matrix to replace the NAs in these rows with the same single value (lets say 0 or 99, this is irrelevant!)?
But -important- ONLY for the rows which are empty (only NAs)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437164/removing-empty-rows-of-a-data-file-in-r

Comment: NO! This is not a duplicate.

Comment: I need to KEEP the row. I can not delete them.

Comment: @arjwhite: is a great short answer but should also consider having your calculations being `NA`-tolerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to index the rows which are all NA, and then replace them with an assignment. You can achieve this with `is.na()`, `rowSums()`, and `ncol()`. I've written them all out below, so you can see the working:

```
x <- rbind(c(1, 2, NA), c(NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 5, 6), c(7, NA, 9))
x
is.na(x)
rowSums(is.na(x))
ncol(x)
# This is the single line that does all the work
x[rowSums(is.na(x)) == ncol(x),] <- 99
x
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA    5    6
[4,]    7   NA    9
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[1] 1 3 1 1
[1] 3
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2   NA
[2,]   99   99   99
[3,]   NA    5    6
[4,]    7   NA    9
```

Comment: This worked perfect! Thank you a lot! I was really hoping for such a elegant and quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
mdat
          C.1 C.2 C.3
row1        1   2   3
row2       11  12  13
rowpartNA   2   2  NA
rowNA      NA  NA  NA

all.na.fun<- function(x)all(is.na(x))
apply(mdat, 1, all.na.fun)
     row1      row2 rowpartNA     rowNA 
    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE 
> all.na.fun<- function(x)all(is.na(x))
(all.na.row<-apply(mdat, 1, all.na.fun))
     row1      row2 rowpartNA     rowNA 
    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE 
mdat[all.na.row,] <-99
mdat
          C.1 C.2 C.3
row1        1   2   3
row2       11  12  13
rowpartNA   2   2  NA
rowNA      99  99  99
```

Answer (score 1):

The matrix:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,
             NA,NA,NA,NA,
             NA, 1, 2, 3,
             1,2, NA, 4, 
             4,2,1,3),  nrow=5, byrow = T )
```

The syntax:

```
m[which(rowSums(is.na(m))==ncol(m)),]=999
```

The output:

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]  999  999  999  999
[3,]   NA    1    2    3
[4,]    1    2   NA    4
[5,]    4    2    1    3
```