# Ignoring values or NAs in the sample function

Tags: r, matrix, sample, apply

I have a matrix in R that I would like to take a single random sample from each row.  Some of my data is in NA, but when taking the random sample I do not want the NA to be an option for the sampling.  How would I accomplish this?

For example,

```
a <- matrix (c(rep(5, 10), rep(10, 10), rep(NA, 5)), ncol=5, nrow=5)
a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5    5   10   10   NA
[2,]    5    5   10   10   NA
[3,]    5    5   10   10   NA
[4,]    5    5   10   10   NA
[5,]    5    5   10   10   NA
```

When I apply the sample function to this matrix to output another matrix I get

```
b <- matrix(apply(a, 1, sample, size=1), ncol=1)
b

     [,1]
[1,]   NA
[2,]   NA
[3,]   10
[4,]   10
[5,]    5
```

Instead I do not want the NA to be capable of being the output and want the output to be something like:

```
b
     [,1]
[1,]   10
[2,]   10
[3,]   10
[4,]    5
[5,]   10
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There might be a better way but sample doesn't appear to have any parameters related to NAs so instead I just wrote an anonymous function to deal with the NAs.

```
apply(a, 1, function(x){sample(x[!is.na(x)], size = 1)})
```

essentially does what you want.  If you really want the matrix output you could do

```
b <- matrix(apply(a, 1, function(x){sample(x[!is.na(x)], size = 1)}), ncol = 1)
```

---

Edit: You didn't ask for this but my proposed solution does fail in certain cases (mainly if a row contains ONLY NAs.

```
a <- matrix (c(rep(5, 10), rep(10, 10), rep(NA, 5)), ncol=5, nrow=5)
# My solution works fine with your example data
apply(a, 1, function(x){sample(x[!is.na(x)], size = 1)})

# What happens if a row contains only NAs
a[1,] <- NA

# Now it doesn't work
apply(a, 1, function(x){sample(x[!is.na(x)], size = 1)})

# We can rewrite the function to deal with that case
mysample <- function(x, ...){
    if(all(is.na(x))){
        return(NA)
    }
    return(sample(x[!is.na(x)], ...))
}

# Using the new function things work.
apply(a, 1, mysample, size = 1)
```

Comment: yes, I noticed that failure.  I take the sample from this and use it to generate more replicates from which I take more samples.  I made a work around but your solution is better than mine.

Answer (score 4):

I think @Dason's solution works quite well, but you can also try this:

```
a <- matrix (c(rep(5, 10), rep(10, 10), rep(NA, 5)), ncol=5, nrow=5)
matrix(sample(na.omit(as.numeric(a)),ncol(a)))
     [,1]
[1,]   10
[2,]    5
[3,]   10
[4,]   10
[5,]    5
```

Even if there is a complete row with NA's or a complete column with NA'S, this solution can deal with perfectly, for instance:

```
set.seed(007)
a <- matrix(sample(1:100, 25), 5)
a[1,] <- NA
a[5,1] <- NA
a[,3] <- NA
a[5,5] <- NA
a[3,2] <- NA

matrix(sample(na.omit(as.numeric(a)),ncol(a)))
     [,1]
[1,]   40
[2,]    1
[3,]   42
[4,]   26
[5,]   32
```

I guess this is what you were looking for (at least this could be another approach).

Answer (score 0):

Tried some of the solutions above, but for some reason, I kept getting this error:

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob): 
     invalid first argument
```

This code (which uses `sample_n` (from `dplyr`) and [`complete.cases`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame)) works like a charm, and is pretty straightforward, IMHO:

```
sample_n(df[complete.cases(df), ], n)
```