# Sample without the NAs

Tags: r

This question is quiet related to the question asked in the following page of stackoverflow:[Ignoring values or NAs in the sample function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970116/ignoring-values-or-nas-in-the-sample-function/10262352#10262352?newreg=0230cc2cda8e42bf98237ebf08cccbee)

Question: I have a matrix K of (say 1528) rows and many (say 1000) columns. There are NAs in many of the entries. From each column I want to sample 40 elements in the following way: I randomly sample from the non NA elements if the total of such elements in the column is not less than 40. if they are less than 40 (say=k), there will be all the k elements and 40-k NAs. I have tried the following code:

```
mysample <- function(x){
  if(sum(is.na(x))>1488){
    sum(x[!is.na(x)])
    return(c(x[!is.na(x)],rep(NA,40-sum(x[!is.na(x)]))))
  }
  return(sample(x[!is.na(x)],40))
}

J=apply(K, 2, mysample)
```

In the fourth line, it is showing invalid 'times' argument in the repeat. Can anyone make the code workable (I want to include the NAs since I want to produce a 40X1000 matrix out of it)

Comment: Sorry: found the answer myself:    mysample <- function(x){
  if(sum(is.na(x))>1488){
    return(c(x[!is.na(x)],rep(NA,40))[1:40])
  }
  return(sample(x[!is.na(x)],40))
}

J=apply(K, 2, mysample)
                                                                                                                     Thanks to all the previous discussions in the forum. My code was a direct extension of them

Answer (score 2):

In your `rep` function, the time parameter should be `40 - length_of_nona` which should be `40 - sum(!is.na(x))`. Didn't test, but I think that will fix the problem:

```
mysample <- function(x){
  if(sum(is.na(x))>1488){
    # sum(x[!is.na(x)])
    return(c(x[!is.na(x)],rep(NA,40-sum(!is.na(x)))))
                                        ^        ^
  }
  return(sample(x[!is.na(x)],40))
}

J=apply(K, 2, mysample)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Psidom, I will check it