# dplyr group_by and sample whilst ignoring NA

Tags: r, dplyr, na, sample

I would like to gapfill NA values for each group by sampling non NA values from the same group.

This is the closest to what I'd like to achieve using `!is.na()` [Ignoring values or NAs in the sample function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970116/ignoring-values-or-nas-in-the-sample-function).

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(len = c(NA, 45447.4157838775, 161037.71538108, 
78147.8550470324, 7193.48815617057, 1571.95459212405, 18191.381972185, 
20366.2132412031, 10014.987524596, 1403.72511829297, 5651.17842991513, 
6848.03271105711, 8043.32937011393, 8926.65133418451, 5808.44456603825, 
2208.14264175252, 1797.4936747033, 5325.76651327694, 2660.66730207955, 
5844.07912541444, 3956.40473896271, 959.873314407621, 3294.01472360025, 
5221.94864001864, 3781.51913857335, 7811.83819953768, 3387.20323328623, 
5514.92099458441, 5792.54371531706, 5643.98385143961, 15478.916809379, 
8401.66533205217, 7046.25074819247, 2734.73639821402, NA, 62332.3343404513, 
NA, 46563.1214718113, 25590.4020105238, 13015.3682275862, 4984.80432801441, 
NA), point = c(NA, 0, 8, 5, 2, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 6, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, NA, 
10, NA, 19, 6, 5, 0, NA), country = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("WCY_____ES", "WCY_____FR", 
"WCY_____IT"), class = "factor"), group = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)

data1 <- data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(nulen = if_else(country == 'WCY_____FR', len, sample(len[!is.na(len)], 1, TRUE)),
         nupoint = if_else(country == 'WCY_____FR', point, sample(point[!is.na(point)], 1, TRUE)))
```

But instead I get `Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument`

There should be no significant difference between the known and gapfilled distributions. If there are no values to sample from the same group (either other values are `NA` or there is only one row in the ```group``) then the sample should be taken from the entire dataset. Any package is fine.

Comment: Please add a sample of your data using `dput()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea,

```
dd %>%
    mutate(len1 = replace(len, is.na(len), sample(len[!is.na(len)], 1, TRUE)),
           point1 = replace(point, is.na(point), sample(point[!is.na(point)], 1, TRUE))) %>%
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(nulen = ifelse(all(is.na(len)) & country == 'WCY_____FR', len1, 
                          ifelse(is.na(len) & country == 'WCY_____FR', sample(len[!is.na(len)], 1, TRUE), len)))
```

which gives,

> ```
> len point country    group    len1 point1   nulen
>      <dbl> <dbl> <fct>      <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
>  1     NA     NA WCY_____ES     1   1572.      0     NA 
>  2  45447.     0 WCY_____FR     2  45447.      0  45447.
>  3 161038.     8 WCY_____FR     2 161038.      8 161038.
>  4  78148.     5 WCY_____FR     2  78148.      5  78148.
>  5   7193.     2 WCY_____FR     3   7193.      2   7193.
>  6   1572.     0 WCY_____FR     3   1572.      0   1572.
>  7  18191.     9 WCY_____FR     3  18191.      9  18191.
>  8  20366.     0 WCY_____FR     3  20366.      0  20366.
>  9  10015.     0 WCY_____FR     3  10015.      0  10015.
> 10   1404.     0 WCY_____FR     3   1404.      0   1404.
> # ... with 32 more rows
> ```

The same can be done for `point` as well.

Comment: Thanks but I did ask "If there are no values to sample from the same group then the sample should be taken from the entire dataset." I've edited the question to be more explicit.

Comment: @user3725599 Please have a look and let me know

Comment: Not quite. There are still NA values. I've added nulen2 = ifelse(is.na(nulen), len1, nulen) but can't think of a less clunky fix. And the sampled values are identical.