# Exclude Blank and NA in R

Tags: r, na

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R - remove rows with NAs in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/r-remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame)

I have a dataframe named sub.new with multiple columns in it. And I'm trying to exclude any cell containing `NA` or a `blank space` "".
I tried to use `subset()`, but it's targeting specific column conditional. Is there anyway to scan through the whole dataframe and create a subset that no cell is either `NA` or `blank space` ?

In the example below, only the first line should be kept:

```
# ID               SNP             ILMN_Strand   Customer_Strand
ID1234              [A/G]          TOP           BOT
Non-Specific        NSB (Bgnd)     Green
Non-Polymorphic     NP (A)         Red
Non-Polymorphic     NP (T)         Purple
Non-Polymorphic     NP (C)         Green
Non-Polymorphic     NP (G)         Blue
Restoration         Restore        Green
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: what didnt work out about them? can you give us some example data?

Comment: Are you working with vectors? Dataframes? If dataframes what do you want should happen if only one element in the row is blank or NA?  Please provide more details.

Comment: I did searches, but it doesn't work out.

Comment: @user1301840: Googling "R remove rows with NA", or searching StackOverflow with that phrase, both give the above question as the top result.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame) has some good answers on additional ways to remove `NA`s from the dataset.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

A good idea is to set all of the "" (blank cells) to NA before any further analysis.

If you are reading your input from a file, it is a good choice to cast all "" to NAs:

```
foo <- read.table(file="Your_file.txt", na.strings=c("", "NA"), sep="\t") # if your file is tab delimited
```

If you have already your table loaded, you can act as follows:

```
foo[foo==""] <- NA
```

Then to keep only rows with no NA you may just use `na.omit()`:

```
foo <- na.omit(foo)
```

Or to keep columns with no NA:

```
foo <- foo[, colSums(is.na(foo)) == 0]
```

Comment: It does the trick, but it removed all the rows. I guess I still have to narrow down to the columns that I want to do the NA check. Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Indeed above question has been asked before but if one has blank cells as opposed to NA ones then this is very useful.

Comment: Can you please specify what is `na.omit`? There is no package `na` in R 3.1.1.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영, `na.omit()` is a function in the base package of R. Periods don't denote functions in R as they do in Python.

Comment: With dplyr, it's possible to write this in a short and readable way like this: `foo %>% na_if("") %>% na.omit`

Answer (score 11):

Don't know exactly what kind of dataset you have, so I provide general answer.

```
x <- c(1,2,NA,3,4,5)
y <- c(1,2,3,NA,6,8)
my.data <- data.frame(x, y)
> my.data
   x  y
1  1  1
2  2  2
3 NA  3
4  3 NA
5  4  6
6  5  8
# Exclude rows with NA values
my.data[complete.cases(my.data),]
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 2
5 4 6
6 5 8
```

Comment: does this exclude "" as well?

Comment: No. I suggest you first define what kind of NA values you have in your dataset.

Comment: You could first convert "" values to NA by doing something similar to this `my.data[my.data == ""] <- NA` and then use the answer provided.

Comment: @Andrej I don't quite understand "what kind of NA values", all it displays just NA.

Comment: You have to recode all "" occurrences to NA, as @Dason suggest

Comment: thanks for all the help, I guess I'm good from here now.