# Count rows of a data frame which do not contain `NA`

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R - remove rows with NAs in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/r-remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame)

I have a data frame derived from the following function:

```
complete <- function(directory,id = 1:332) {

   csvfiles <- sprintf("/Users/myname/Desktop/%s/%03d.csv", directory, id)

   nrows <- sapply( csvfiles, function(f) nrow(read.csv(f)))

        rowlabels <- nrow(nrows)

        data.frame(id=sprintf('%3d', id), 
            nobs=sapply(csvfiles,function(x) length(count.fields(x))),
            row.names=rowlabels
           )
       }
```

This function counts the number of rows in each file contained within the directory produced by the object csvfiles. It then outputs a data frame showing the file number along with the count of rows (so two columns)

Thought I had it but problem is that I must now exclude rows within each file where an instance of `NA` exists.

How would I edit this to ignore those rows in each file and just count the rows where no `NA`s exist?

Comment: This is your N-th post here with R-project in the title.  That is redundant.  Just use the `[r]` tags as you've done. And feel free to read some other posts.

Comment: Have a look at `?complete.cases`. Having done this same online course a few months back, I'm pretty sure it gets mentioned in the lectures at some point, keep an ear out for hints like that.

Comment: Please search before posting again. Two minutes on google or the s.o. search would have found your answer.

Comment: Your response to @thelatemail places a big, blinking neon sign above your head that screams "I did not read the question shown to me, nor have I bothered to read the documentation on the function in question."

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The OP is not asking how to remove rows, he's asking how to count complete rows.  And yes, this is a "homework question."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this line:

> `nrows <- sapply( csvfiles, function(f) nrow(read.csv(f)))`

with this line, which uses the `complete.cases` function:

> `nrows <- sapply( csvfiles, function(f) nrow(complete.cases(read.csv(f))))`

`complete.cases` takes a data frame and returns a data frame with the same columns, but with all the rows which contain at least one `NA` thrown out.

Comment: Hmm, for me, `complete.cases` seems to return a logical vector, not a filtered data frame.  So I had to execute `sum`, not `nrow`

Comment: -1 , complete cases doesn't return a filtered dataframe but a logical vector.
please correct this :)