# Converting from a character to a numeric data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a character data frame in R which has `NaN`s in it. I need to remove any row with a `NaN` and then convert it to a numeric data frame.

If I just do as.numeric on the data frame, I run into the following

```
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
 1:
 0:
```

Comment: have a look at `complete.cases` and see also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As @thijs van den bergh    points you to,

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c("NaN","2"),y=c("NaN","3"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dat <- as.data.frame(sapply(dat, as.numeric)) #<- sapply is here

dat[complete.cases(dat), ]
#  x y
#2 2 3
```

Is *one* way to do this.

Your error comes from trying to make a `data.frame` numeric. The `sapply` option I show is instead making each column vector numeric.

Comment: Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) :
  (converted from warning) NAs introduced by coercion
 1: as.data.frame(sapply(time, as.numeric))
 2: sapply(time, as.numeric)
 3: lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
 4: .signalSimpleWarning("NAs introduced by coercion", quote(lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)))
 5: withRestarts({
 6: withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1]])
 7: doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)

Comment: Not sure how you mean, which sapply options?

Comment: Both the solutions dont work, I am getting the same error, maybe I am missing something?

Comment: like I said in my comment, if you provide some sample data we can get to the bottom of this. :) Try posting the output of `dput(yourdata)`

Comment: I will try and make sense of the answers guys, I think I am fumbling smwhr, but shud be able to help myself :)

Answer (score 10):

Note that `data.frames` are not `numeric` or `character`, but rather are a `list` which can be all `numeric` columns, all `character` columns, or a mix of these or other types (e.g.: `Date`/`logical`).

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c("NaN","2"),y=c("NaN","3"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
is.list(dat)
# [1] TRUE
```

The example data just has two character columns:

```
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: chr  "NaN" "2"
 $ y: chr  "NaN" "3
```

...which you could add a numeric column to like so:

```
> dat$num.example <- c(6.2,3.8)
> dat
    x   y num.example
1 NaN NaN         6.2
2   2   3         3.8
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x          : chr  "NaN" "2"
 $ y          : chr  "NaN" "3"
 $ num.example: num  6.2 3.8
```

So, when you try to do `as.numeric` R gets confused because it is wondering how to convert this list object which may have multiple types in it. `user1317221_G`'s answer uses the `?sapply` function, which can be used to apply a function to the individual items of an object. You could alternatively use `?lapply` which is a very similar function (read more on the `*apply` functions here - [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) )

I.e. - in this case, to each column of your `data.frame`, you can apply the `as.numeric` function, like so:

```
data.frame(lapply(dat,as.numeric))
```

The `lapply` call is wrapped in a `data.frame` to make sure the output is a `data.frame` and not a `list`. That is, running:

```
lapply(dat,as.numeric)
```

will give you:

```
> lapply(dat,as.numeric)
$x
[1] NaN   2

$y
[1] NaN   3

$num.example
[1] 6.2 3.8
```

While:

```
data.frame(lapply(dat,as.numeric))
```

will give you:

```
>  data.frame(lapply(dat,as.numeric))
    x   y num.example
1 NaN NaN         6.2
2   2   3         3.8
```

Comment: great answer. But R needs to fix this. Its things like this that turn people away from our community.