# How to select rows in a data.frame without NA values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame called data. I want to create a function f(data, collist). This function takes data and a list of columns from data itself, and returns only those rows from data, for which the mentioned column names in collist are not NA. I know it can be done using for loop, but I want to do it without using for loop.

Also, please let me know if it is generally more efficient in R to avoid loops.

Here is an example:

```
 A   B   C   D
 1   2  NA  NA
 2  NA  NA  NA
NA   3   7   5
NA   4   2  NA
 5   6  NA  NA
```

If collist contains B and C, then a reduced data frame with row number 1,3,4 would be returned. The reason being either B or C or both has NA in rows 2 and 5. I want a function, because I will be using this operation quite a number of times. Through this question, I will learn some new R tricks, as well as, make my whole program more elegant. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear enough. I want to return as a data frame only those rows, for which all the mentioned columns in collist are non-NA. In KDB/Q I can pass index, as I think it is more efficient to pass index numbers rather than the full subset data, and then using those index, I can easily choose those indexes from main data in KDB/Q. Not sure what would be most optimal in R - to send indexes  or to send the subset data. If index, how do I use that index to extract the rows from data in main function?

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. What if let say instead of removing NA, I want to remove Inf or where any data is less than 0. How would I make that work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove rows with NAs in data.frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are just looking for `complete.cases`. Here's an example:

```
#### SAMPLE DATA

set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(rnorm(20), 5)
m[sample(length(m), 7)] <- NA
mydf <- data.frame(m)
mydf
#           X1         X2        X3          X4
# 1         NA -0.8204684  1.511781 -0.04493361
# 2  0.1836433  0.4874291        NA          NA
# 3 -0.8356286  0.7383247        NA  0.94383621
# 4  1.5952808         NA -2.214700  0.82122120
# 5  0.3295078         NA        NA  0.59390132

#### SAMPLE EXTRACTION

collist <- c("X1", "X2")
mydf[complete.cases(mydf[collist]), collist]
#           X1        X2
# 2  0.1836433 0.4874291
# 3 -0.8356286 0.7383247
```

Comment: @Sumit, Do you want to keep the `NA` in those cases? That's quite a different question, but if you search SO, I'm sure you'll find some examples of how to do exactly that. Keep in mind that comparison operators will often yield `TRUE` and `FALSE` outputs which can be used to subset your data.

Comment: Your answer answers my question partially. I want all the columns (x1,x2,x3,x4) with rows 2 and 3 as given in your example.

Comment: @Sumit, then write your questions more clearly. Simply delete the second "collist" in the last line. If you don't understand what that is doing, then you need to read up on basic subsetting and extracting data from R before you can get much further with R.

Comment: Ok. Got the answer. mydf[complete.cases(mydf[collist]),] would do the trick.