# 5 numbers summary I got 6 numbers

Tags: r

I have one column of with 10000 rows, and I want to separate those numbers based on their density. So I use `summary()` to see a big picture of it, but I got 6 numbers summary, the last one is NA's. But there shouldn't be any NAs, because this is a result of a for loop, and I already eliminate all "inf"s. How can I see where are these NAs and delete them?
Here is the result

```
summary(HOT$score)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
0.945   2.714   5.180   5.612   7.976  21.420      97
```

Thank you for any idea in advance.

Thanks to all commenters help, I found those NAs. But I can't figure out why it get NA.
This is a result of running `max()`. say

```
c<-c(21:30)
d<-c(31:40) 
bb<-as.data.frame(cbind(c,d))
h=42
max(bb$c[which(h<bb$c)])
[1] -Inf
Warning message:
In max(bb$c[which(h < bb$c)]) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

so if it doesn't have result, it will return -Inf, I don't know how the result would be NA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove rows with NAs in data.frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame)

Comment: You probably shouldn't just remove the `NA`'s. Getting unexpected answers like this is usually the result of a bug in the calculations. Look at where you get `NA`'s and if there is a pattern in  `HOT[is.na(HOT$score), ]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see which rows have NA's in the column of interest, type `HOT[is.na(HOT$score), ]`. To remove rows with `NA`s, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame).

Answer (score 0):

`HOT <- HOT[!is.na(HOT$score),]`

should sort you. If you have further problems, leave a comment.