# Getting the value of columns for which more than one value exists in a dataframe

Tags: r

If I have a dataframe in R like this,

```
1 2 abc bh abd NA NA
2 3 abc NA NA NA NA 
3 4 NA  NA ad yu ae
...................
```

I want to get those values in columns 1 and 2 which have more than one value in the rest of the column. For example, here, `1 2` has 3 values and `3 4` has 3 values as well and `2 3` has only one value and rest are NA. So, I want `1 2` and `3 4`. How can I do it in R?
Thanks!

Comment: Chan- This looks like a slightly different version of the question you asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26197648/3897439).  Both questions could likely have been solved with a little searching.  For example, with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4862178/3897439) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- read.table(text="1 2 abc bh abd NA NA
2 3 abc NA NA NA NA 
3 4 NA  NA ad yu ae")

x[rowSums(!is.na(x[, -1:-2])) > 1, 1:2]
#  V1 V2
#1  1  2
#3  3  4
```

`!is.na(x[, -1:-2])` returns a matrix of TRUE/FALSE values.  `rowSums` converts TRUE values to 1 and FALSE values to 0 and sums them by row.  Subset to only include rows where that is greater than 1, and return columns `1:2`.