# Delete rows containing character "N/A" in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame. Some of the rows in various columns contain #N/A (imported from Excel). I want to delete these rows that have #N/A. How do I do this.

Comment: Start by providing a reproducible example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove rows with NAs in data.frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame)

Comment: @user1436187, quite likely that it's a duplicate, but probably not of the question you linked to, since those values here (#NA) are not real NAs in R.

Comment: This is actually a good question. na.omit() does not remove entries with values 'n/a'. any(is.na(data)) returns FALSE despite several columns containing 'n/a'. In python dropna() removes everything though

Answer (score 4):

If you have a file that looks like this

```
cat(x <- "a b f a\n#N/A a n b\nB #N/A #N/A c")
# a b f a
# #N/A a n b
# B #N/A #N/A c
```

You can read the data into R with `read.table`, making use of the `na.strings` argument while adjusting the `comment.char` argument accordingly.

```
(df <- read.table(text = x, na.strings = "#N/A", comment.char = ""))
#     V1   V2   V3 V4
# 1    a    b    f  a
# 2 <NA>    a    n  b
# 3    B <NA> <NA>  c
```

Then call `na.omit` to remove all rows that contain `NA`

```
na.omit(df)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  a  b  f  a
```

To read from file, replace `text = x` with the file name

Comment: to delete rows you need `complete.cases`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  `na.omit` works as well to remove rows with `NA` values