# Complex subsetting data set to data frame

Tags: r, subset, reshape, reshape2, melt

**1)** I would like to do a subset operation in Gnu R with the data set [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109495328/WDI_Data_final.csv) to have a resulting data frame only with Brazil, Time and all the Series Name about Income share (like "Income share held by lowest 10%", ""Income share held by lowest 20%" and so on). In total there would be 7 Series Names about Income Share.

I tried the following command but cannot subset more than one "Series.Name":

```
test <- melt(subset(WDI, subset = Series.Name == "Income share held by lowest 10%", select = -c(Time.Code, Series.Code, Argentina, Canada, Chile, Colombia, Mexico, USA, Venezuela)), id.vars = c("Series.Name", "Time"))
```

**2)** In an additional second step I would like to delete all rows with NA values.

The complete code I use is the following:

```
WDI <- read.csv(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109495328/WDI_Data_final.csv, na.strings = "..")
library(reshape)
library(reshape2)
WDI <- rename(WDI, (c(Argentina..ARG.="Argentina", Brazil..BRA.="Brazil", Canada..CAN.="Canada", Chile..CHL.="Chile", Colombia..COL.="Colombia", Mexico..MEX.="Mexico", United.States..USA.="USA", Venezuela..RB..VEN.="Venezuela")))
income_brazil_long <- melt(subset(WDI, subset = Series.Name == "Income share held by lowest 10%", select = -c(Time.Code, Series.Code, Argentina, Canada, Chile, Colombia, Mexico, USA, Venezuela)), id.vars = c("Series.Name", "Time"))
```

Comment: The data set in question measure 128 kb in size. I thought it might be better to provide the original data rather than to make up some random data in order to prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame in case also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your data, this is actually probably easiest using `grepl` to help with the subsetting.

We use `grepl` to search through the "Series.Name" column for any rows that include the string "Income share held". That creates a logical vector indicating the rows we want. The columns we want are the first, the third, and the sixth.

Wrap it all in `na.omit` to get rid of any rows with `NA` values.

```
WDI_Brazil <- na.omit(WDI[grepl("Income share held", WDI$Series.Name), 
                          c(1, 3, 6)])
```

The data are already "long", so there's no need to `melt`. What does the `data.frame` look like?

```
summary(WDI_Brazil)
#                            Series.Name      Time       Brazil..BRA.   
#  Income share held by fourth 20% :28   Min.   :1981   Min.   : 0.600  
#  Income share held by highest 10%:28   1st Qu.:1988   1st Qu.: 2.895  
#  Income share held by highest 20%:28   Median :1996   Median :10.320  
#  Income share held by lowest 10% :28   Mean   :1996   Mean   :20.948  
#  Income share held by lowest 20% :28   3rd Qu.:2004   3rd Qu.:43.797  
#  Income share held by second 20% :28   Max.   :2012   Max.   :67.310  
#  (Other)                         :28                                  
table(droplevels(WDI_Brazil$Series.Name))
# 
#  Income share held by fourth 20% Income share held by highest 10% Income share held by highest 20% 
#                               28                               28                               28 
#  Income share held by lowest 10%  Income share held by lowest 20%  Income share held by second 20% 
#                               28                               28                               28 
#   Income share held by third 20% 
#                               28
```

Notice that there are seven factor levels in "Series.Name", as expected.

Comment: Awesome! Like it for the clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do what you are looking for with `base` functions.

```
WDI <- read.csv("WDI_Data_final.csv", header=T, na.strings="..")

# The colnames are strange from the file so reset for clarity
colnames(WDI) <- c("Series.Name", "Series.Code", "Time","Time.Code","Argentina",
                   "Brazil", "Canada", "Chile", "Colombia","Mexico",
                   "USA", "Venezuela")

# do the subsetting
test <- with(WDI, 
             WDI[Series.Name=="Income share held by lowest 10%",
                 c("Brazil","Time", "Series.Name")])

# if you want more, use %in% and specify the Series.Names you care about
test <- with(WDI, 
             WDI[Series.Name %in% c("Income share held by lowest 10%", 
                                    "Income share held by lowest 20%"),
                 c("Brazil","Time", "Series.Name")])

# if you want all the 'income shares', the grepl solution above  by
# Ananda is the most concise.

# you can then use reshape2::melt
melted_test <- melt(test, id.vars=c("Series.Name", "Time"))
```

To remove the `NA` just use `complete.cases`

```
test[complete.cases(test),]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, cdeterman. I learned with your answer that my code is too complicated. Did not know that `colnames` exist. Thumbs up, man!