# How to filter rows out of data.table where any column is NA without specifying columns individually

Tags: r, data.table

Given a data.table

```
DT<-data.table(a=c(1,2,NA,4,5), b=c(2,3,4,NA,5),c=c(1,2,3,4,5),d=c(2,3,4,5,6))
```

how can I do the equivalent of

```
DT[!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & !is.na(c) & !is.na(d)]
```

in a general form without knowing any of the column names or typing out the `!is.na()` for each individual column.

I could also do

`DT[apply(DT,1,function(x) !any(is.na(x)))]` but I'm wondering if there's a better way still.

Comment: Take a look here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments of @docendodiscimus

`data.table` has an `na.omit` method which is optimized for `data.table`s

Answer (score 11):

I think you are looking for `complete.cases`:

```
> DT[complete.cases(DT),]
   a b c d
1: 1 2 1 2
2: 2 3 2 3
3: 5 5 5 6
```

Comment: Or perhaps `na.omit(DT)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus not sure if you suggested `na.omit` with this in mind but after further review it looks like there's a `na.omit` function within `data.table` as opposed to just the base function.  In any event, it didn't even occur to me to use that function even though it is completely obvious in retrospect.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor, when I posted the comment I had a feeling that `na.omit` is optimized for `data.table` but wasn't really sure (and didn't bother looking it up).

Comment: Yes, `na.omit` has `data.table` method. See `methods(na.omit)`. It also has a `col` argument where you can specify according to which columns you want to omit `NA`s. I'd guess that would be the perfect choice here.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this:

```
DT[!is.na(rowSums(DT)),]
```

Comment: This only works if all columns are numeric/integer/logical, wouldn't work if any column was `character` or `factor`.