# Remove rows that contain at least an NA only if one column contains a specific value

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, na

I have the following data frame:

```
a  b  c
x  1  1
x  1  NA
y  NA 1
y  1  1
```

I would like to remove the rows containing at least an NA in any column(s), but only if the "a" column contains a "y". So, the result would be:

```
a  b  c
x  1  1
x  1  NA
y  1  1
```

So far I have tried this:

```
my_DF %>%
  filter(!(any(is.na(.)) & a == "y"))
```

but the resulting data frame is the following:

```
a  b  c
x  1  1
x  1  NA
```

so this just removes any row in which "a" contains a "y", regardless of whether the row also contains NAs in at least one column.

How could I change the "any(is.na(.))" part of the command (I guess that is the wrong part) in other for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new [`if_any`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) approach, introduced in [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) 1.0.4, and used within the `filter` function. The following code will achieve the result you're after:

```
my_DF %>% 
filter(!(a == "y" & if_any(everything(), ~ is.na(.x))))
```

**Explanation of individual bits**

`filter` - keep all rows where

`!` - it's not true that

`everything()` - check all columns (alternatively, you could specify a vector of column names, e.g. `c("b", "c")`)

`if_any(everything(), ~ is.na(.x))` - if any column has NA (there is also an `if_all` version)

**Full reproducible example**

```
my_DF <- data.frame(a = c("x", "x", "y", "y"),
                    b = c(1, 1, NA, 1),
                    c = c(1, NA, 1, 1))
my_DF %>% 
filter(!(a == "y" & if_any(everything(), ~ is.na(.x))))
```

Comment: I like more this approach (using dplyr)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
my_DF <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"a  b  c
x  1  1
x  1  NA
y  NA 1
y  1  1")
i <- apply(is.na(my_DF), 1, any) & my_DF$a=="y"
my_DF[!i,]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_df)
my_df <- my_df[!complete_cases(my_df),][a == 'y',]
```

This thread answers your question I guess - [How to filter rows out of data.table where any column is NA without specifying columns individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766492/how-to-filter-rows-out-of-data-table-where-any-column-is-na-without-specifying-c)

Answer (score 0):

In base R you may do

```r
my_DF <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
                      "a  b  c
x  1  1
x  1  NA
y  NA 1
y  1  1")

my_DF[rowSums(is.na(my_DF)) == 0 | my_DF$a == 'x',]
#>   a b  c
#> 1 x 1  1
#> 2 x 1 NA
#> 4 y 1  1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>