# Excluding column of null values for complete.cases in R

Tags: r, null, na

I need to exclude one column of which I know it merely contains null values.
I've used [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame) as example before, but I'm not sure how I can exclude a column.

There is several different data frames like the one below but with different amount of columns, on eachone I want all NA's except the ones in the last column.

```
PIG_ID      WEIGHT HERD_YEAR_BIRTH BIRTH_MONTH PARITY_BLL_DAM SEX_CODE LIVE_BORN_LITTER LIVE_BORN_LITTER2 VALID_COLUMN
13513130           7.5      65433130215          09              2        Z                9                81         <NA>
654605132           7.0      5646846421          04              3        Z                4                16         <NA>
654068065           4.0      5530201049          <NA>              3        B               15               225         <NA>
```

How can I get this done with complete.cases?

Expected output would be:

```
PIG_ID      WEIGHT HERD_YEAR_BIRTH BIRTH_MONTH PARITY_BLL_DAM SEX_CODE LIVE_BORN_LITTER LIVE_BORN_LITTER2 VALID_COLUMN
13513130           7.5      65433130215          09              2        Z                9                81         <NA>
654605132           7.0      5646846421          04              3        Z                4                16         <NA>
```

Comment: If your description is to remove the last column, why is the expected output showing that column?

Comment: Sorry @akrun ! I wrote the description wrongly! What I need is to remove all NA's except for the ones in the last column

Comment: Updated the post.  Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We apply the `complete.cases` on subset of dataset without the 'VALID_COLUMN' and use that as row index.

```
df1[complete.cases(df1[setdiff(names(df1), 'VALID_COLUMN')]),]
#     PIG_ID WEIGHT HERD_YEAR_BIRTH BIRTH_MONTH PARITY_BLL_DAM SEX_CODE
#1  13513130    7.5     65433130215          09              2        Z
#2 654605132    7.0      5646846421          04              3        Z
#  LIVE_BORN_LITTER LIVE_BORN_LITTER2 VALID_COLUMN
#1                9                81         <NA>
#2                4                16         <NA>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I formulated my description wrongly when I posted the question=(