# Remove lines empty element (NULL) with readHTMLTable()

Tags: html, xml, r, html-table

I try to remove rows in HTML table with almost one empty element, represents by (NULL) using readHTMLTable() function in XLM package without success. In my code:

```
require(httr)
require(XML)
```

### Function for read HTML table

```
readFE<- function (x, URL = ""){
FILE <- GET(url=URL)
     tables <- getNodeSet(htmlParse(FILE), "//table") 
     FE_tab <- readHTMLTable(tables[[1]], 
                        header = c("empresa","desc_projeto","desc_regiao", 
                                   "cadastrador_por","cod_talhao","descricao", 
                                   "formiga_area","qtd_destruido","latitude", 
                                   "longitude","data_cadastro"), 
                        colClasses = c("character","character","character", 
                                       "character","character","character", 
                                       "character","character","character", 
                                       "character","character"), 
                        trim = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE 
)     
     x<-NULL
     results <- x
     x<-FE_tab[-(1),]
     results <- x
     results
}
```

## --

## Exemple

```
tableFE<-readFE(URL="https://www.dropbox.com/s/mb316ghr4irxipr/TALHOES_AGENTES.htm?dl=1")
tableFE
```

Someone could help me?

Thanks,

Alexandre

Comment: So do you want to remove the rows which has 0.00 in the entry?

Comment: No I want to remove the rows with NULL, because I have 0 as numeric result.

Comment: Using `results<-results[!apply(results,1,function(x){ any(x=="(NULL)")}),]` at the end of your `readFE` function will discard any rows containing the string (NULL).

Comment: [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame) This link posted here has the answer for that.

Comment: Thank you fishtank, the function work. But if I try results<-results[!apply(results,1,function(x){any(x==0.00000000)}),] for eliminated Latitude and Longitude with 0.0000 doesn't work. Can you help me?