# faster way to run a loop in r

Tags: r, loops

I have three dataframes A,B and C.

A has 18000 rows and 18000 columns and B has 150000 rows and 5 cols.

I want to fill elements of A by B.

the loop take a long time. how can I run this loop faster?

example of A

```
Entrez_Gene_Id 2324 34345 4345 1234 3453
1 Entrez_Gene_Id    0     0    0    0    0
2          23040    0     0    0    0    0
3           7249    0     0    0    0    0
4          64478    0     0    0    0    0
5           4928    0     0    0    0    0
6          58191    0     0    0    0    0
```

example of B

```
  head(B)
  V1 Gene1 Gene2      weight   newWeight
1  1  4171  4172  2.01676494 0.020420929
2  2  2237  5111 1.933298567 0.015300857
3  4   506   509 2.439170425 0.020577243
4  7  6635  6636 2.255316779 0.081088975
5  8  6133  6210 3.427969232 0.021132906
6 10 23521  6217 1.607247743 0.027792961
```

and this is my code :

```
B<- data.frame(lapply(C, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for(i in 1:nrow(B)){
  Rname=B[i,2]
  Cname=B[i,3]
  A[Rname,Cname]=B[i,5]
  print(i)
}
```

Comment: can you show what's in `A` &  `B`

Comment: Don't use a loop. Many operations in R are vectorized.

Comment: Try `A[cbind(B[,2],B[,3])] <- B[,5]`

Comment: B is character and A is integer.

Comment: This is an example of a good question. The user not only provides an example of what the data looks like. They also have the output that they want. Please edit your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you are trying to fill a full matrix with a matrix in sparse notation. You can use the `dgCMatrix` class from the `Matrix` package to do this:

```
library(Matrix)
b_mat <- sparseMatrix(i=B[,2],j=B[,3],x=B[,5])
```

This leaves the Matrix in sparse format. To convert to 18,000 x 18,000 form:

```
as.data.frame(as.matrix(b_mat))
```

EDIT: I would suggest leaving the `as.data.frame` call out here, as the `matrix` would be easier to work with considering the number of columns you have

Comment: Interesting package. Can you do a time comparison to `base R` methods?

Comment: @PierreLafortune It doesn't get more efficient than package Matrix when working with sparse matrices.

Comment: @PierreLafortune Matrix is a 'recommended' package expected to be present with every R installation.

Comment: @knifer `B$gene1 <- factor(B$gene1); B$gene2 <- factor(B$gene2); sparseMatrix(i=as.integer(B$gene1),j=as.integer(B$gene1),x=B[,5], dimnames = list(levels(B$gene1), levels(B$gene2)))`