# How to delete part of the columns which includes NA

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks the following:

```
ID1      x1   x2
200      10   NA
200      12   NA
200      13   NA
200      NA   17
200      NA   16
200      NA   19
```

I would like to remove the part of the column that has NA, then I will have an output like this

```
ID1   x1   x2
200   10   17
200   12   16
200   13    19
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Values would always have to shift up, if ID1 is the same. so the values are in the correct columns, but I would like need to replace tha NA in x2 by the values below if ID1 is the same. I'm not sure if that's possible

Comment: Should the 2 in column x1 be a 13?

Comment: In case the 2 is there by mistake you could try `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(ID1) %>% mutate_each(funs(.[order(is.na(.), na.last = FALSE)])) %>% ungroup() %>% filter(rowSums(!is.na(.[-1])) > 0)`

Comment: thanks, this worked!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame here is a better linked example in my opinion.  It uses `complete.cases`, which is pretty start forward, and better yet, easy to remember

Comment: @DaveGruenewald The example you have linked to deals with *removing complete rows* from the dataframe. The Q asks to remove `NAs` *columnwise*, i.e., to shift non-NA values upwards.

Comment: *If* the number of `NA`s is equal in both columns *and* all `NA`s are assembled at start or end of each column, then `na.trim()` from the `zoo` package could be used: `library(data.table); data.table(DF)[, lapply(.SD, zoo::na.trim), by = ID1]`

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with `data.table`.  But, we have to understand that the OP provided a minimal example where the `NA` elements are the same in both the columns 'x1' and 'x2'.  If it is not, this will not work.

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', we loop over the other columns and remove the NA elements with `na.omit`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, na.omit) , by = ID1]
#   ID1 x1 x2
#1: 200 10 17
#2: 200 12 16
#3: 200 13 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
# remove NAs and leave in list of vectors
xclean <- apply(x[2:3],MARGIN = 2,na.omit)

# chance to write code to handle different length vectors

# put in dataframe
data.frame(ID1 = 200,xclean)
```