# Exclude rows that contain NA in a particular column in subsets

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying exclude rows of a subset which contain an NA for a particular column that I choose. I have a CSV spreadsheet of survey data this kind of organization, for instance:

```
name    idnum   term    type      q2    q3
bob     0321    1       2         0     .
.       .       3       1         5     3
ron     .       2       4         2     1
.       2561    4       3         4     2
```

When I was creating my R-workspace, I set it such that `data <- read.csv(..., na.strings='.')`. For purposes of my analysis, I then created subsets by term and type, like `set13 <- subset(data, term=1 & type=2)`, for example. When I trying to conduct t-tests, I noticed that the function threw out any instance of NA, effectively cutting my sample size in half.

For my analysis, I want to exclude responses that are missing survey items, such as Bob from my example, missing question 3. But I still want to include rows that have one or more NAs in the `name` or `idnum` columns. So, in essence, I want to pick by columns which NAs are omitted. (Keep in mind, this is just an example - my actual CSV has about 1000 rows, so each subset may contain 100-150 rows.)

I know this can be done using data frames, but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into my given subset format. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out `complete.cases` as shown in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame) SO post.

```
data[complete.cases(data[,3:6]),]
```

This will return all rows with complete information in columns 3 through 6.

Comment: `data[complete.cases(data[,c(3,7,8)]),]` this would return complete.cases for columns 3,7,8. is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yep, thanks. I think this will solve it, but I can't be sure until I've had some more time to work on the code/stats.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach.

```
data[rowSums(is.na(data[,3:6]))==0,]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is

```
data[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(data[3:6], is.na)),]
```

Comment: Why did you propose this particular solution? Is it faster in general or best practice? (Knowing your typical responses I assume it is better for some reason)

Comment: @Rilcon42 Your solution should be faster as it use `complete.cases`. This is just another option .