# Issue with removing missing values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, na, na.rm

I'm creating a bar chart using ggplot2 in R and I want to remove the missing values in my x-values, I have tried a few different ways of getting ride of "NA"s but nothing seems to change the output.  Currently my code reads (data is not publicly available so I have changed variable names):

```
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x= x_mydata, y= y_mydata, na.rm = TRUE)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom="bar", na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove rows with NAs (missing values) in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame)

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: There is no `na.rm` parameter in `aes`, so that won't do anything. You should remove `NA` values from your data before plotting (or as you pass your data to `data=`.

Comment: Possibly relevant: In `stat_summary` you can pass additional arguments to the function you are using with the `fun.args` argument.  That would look like `fun.args = list(na.rm = TRUE)` in the `stat_summary` layer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want, but wrapping your data name in na.omit should work. So something like ggplot(data = na.omit(df), aes = ...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce. This works just fine

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  x_mydata = c(1, NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, NA),
  y_mydata = c(1,2,NA,4,5, 6,7, NA, NA)
)

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x= x_mydata, y= y_mydata)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom="bar", na.rm = TRUE)
```

Note that there is no `na.rm` aesthetic so you don't need to pass it in the `aes()`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use

```
data = mydata[!is.na(mydata$x_mydata), ]
```

If you are using a data.table, it is more simply

```
data = mydata[!is.na(x_mydata)]
```