# How to remove rows with NAs in all columns using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have:

```
df <-tibble(a=rep(NA, 3), b = c(T,NA,F), c =c("a", NA, "v"))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a     b     c    
  <lgl> <lgl> <chr>
1 NA    TRUE  a    
2 NA    NA    NA   
3 NA    FALSE v
```

and would like to remove all rows being all NA to get this:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  a     b     c    
  <lgl> <lgl> <chr>
1 NA    TRUE  a    
2 NA    FALSE v
```

I would like to have a solution using dplyr in a pipe:

```
df %>% ???
```

*Note*:
This question is different from: 
[Remove rows with all or some NAs (missing values) in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame)
because in the linked question is at least one *not* NA value per row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using filter_all:

```
df %>% filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```