# Using R: How can I delete rows when they contain certain values?

Tags: r

I have a table (737:35) which has different values for missing observations, e.g. NA, 0, n/a or --

So, the table looks like this:

```
┌────┬────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ X  │ Y  │ 2010 │ 2011 │ 2012 │ 2013 │ 2014 │
├────┼────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ A  │ XY │ 0    │ 0    │ 0    │ 10   │ 15   │
│ A  │ XZ │ 11   │ 13   │ n/a  │ 12   │ 14   │
│ B  │ XY │ 0    │ --   │ 0    │ 7    │ --   │
│ B  │ XZ │ 15   │ 16   │ 12   │ 13   │ 14   │
│ C  │ XY │ NA   │ NA   │ NA   │ NA   │ NA   │
│ C  │ XZ │ 8    │ 12   │ 11   │ n/a  │n/a   │
└────┴────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

I want to delete all rows which have a value of either NA, 0, n/a or --, so I end up having only row 5 in this example

I could get rid of the rows with NA using `is.na()`and deleted the rows with a 0 in the column 2010 using `grep()`; could someone tell me how I can delete all rows missing an observation in an easy way?

Comment: Please provide this in reproducible form so we can copy and paste this into R.  Run dput(X) and show the output in the question (where X is your input).  Also clarify exactly what is to be regarded as missing.  Are both NA and "NA" missing?  What about 0 vs. "0"?   I have made some assumptions in my answer but you need to be precise in the question.  Do not answer in the comments. Update the question so it is complete.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4862178/5325862) handles dropping rows with `NA` values and has 16 answers already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be to use `%in%` to check whether values '0', 'n/a', or '--') are present in the column along with `is.na` using `|`, `Reduce` it to a single logical `vector` with `|` to check whether any value in the row have these characters, negate (`!` - meaning none of the elements in the row have that character) and use that o subset the rows

```
i1 <- !Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1, function(x) is.na(x)| x %in% c(0, "n/a", "--")))
df2 <- df1[i1, , drop = FALSE]
#   X  Y 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
#4 B XZ   15   16   12   13   14
```

---

Or using `filter_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     filter_all(all_vars(!(is.na(.) | . %in% c(0, "n/a", "--"))))
#   X  Y 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
#1 B XZ   15   16   12   13   14
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), Y = c("XY", 
"XZ", "XY", "XZ", "XY", "XZ"), `2010` = c(0L, 11L, 0L, 15L, NA, 
8L), `2011` = c("0", "13", "--", "16", NA, "12"), `2012` = c("0", 
"n/a", "0", "12", NA, "11"), `2013` = c("10", "12", "7", "13", 
NA, "n/a"), `2014` = c("15", "14", "--", "14", NA, "n/a")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `apply` to go row by row checking whether any element of that row is in the character vector `na.strings`.  This gives a logical vector of one element per row which where TRUE means the corresponding row has an element found in `na.strings`.  Negate that logical vector and subscript `df1` by it.

```
na.strings <- c(0, NA, "NA", "--", "n/a")
df1[ !apply(df1, 1, function(x) any(x %in% na.strings)), ]
```

This does not distinguish between 0 and "0" or between NA and "NA" but I suspect you want all those to be regarded as missing.  If you did want to distinguish between NA and "NA" and only regard NA but not "NA" as missing then omit "NA" from `na.strings`.

Note that if you are reading this in from a text file then you could specify `na.strings` in your `read.table` command:

```
na.omit(read.table("myfile", na.strings = c("NA", "0", "n/a", "--"), ...whatever...))
```