# I have '?' in my dataset and i want to replace it with A, trying with na.omit but '?' isnt getting replaced with NA

Tags: r

I am using following command to replace '?' with NA but not able to do so.

I want to replace '?' with NA and then omit the rows

```
my_data[my_data == '?'] <- NA
good_data <- na.omit(my_data)
```

Comment: Why not use `na.strings = "?"` in `read.csv/read.table`  In the current code, may be you have some lagging/leading spaces.  What is the output of `my_data == "?"`  Is there any `TRUE` elements

Comment: @amitg have you seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame)?

Comment: @akrun There is no true element with table command. but it is there in dataset. how to identify '?' in the dataset?

Comment: @akrun how i can read the '?' sign from data to be true?

Comment: @AmitG Edit your post to contain the output of `head(my_data)` and `dput(head(my_data))` . That way, we have a better understanding of what your data looks like. Please ensure that one of the rows with '?' is present in your sample