# Selecting Rows with Missing Data in a Range of Columns

Tags: r, data-manipulation, missing-data

There are [several ways](https://statisticsglobe.com/r-find-missing-values/) to identify and manipulate individual cells with missing data in R, e.g., with [`complete.cases`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame) or even [`rowSums`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237363/remove-rows-with-missing-data-in-select-columns-only-if-they-dont-have-missing).

However, I've not been able to find---or figure out myself---an expedient way to select rows that have missing data within a subsetted **range** of columns.

For example, in dataframe `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(D1 = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
                 D2 = c(NA, 0, 1, 1),
                 V1 = c(11, NA, 33, NA),
                 V2 = c(111, 222, NA, NA)
                 )
df

# D1  D2  V1  V2
#  A  NA  11 111    
#  B   0  NA 222    
#  C   1  33  NA    
#  D   1  NA  NA
```

I would like to select all rows that have missing data in *both* columns `V1` *and* `V2`, thus selecting row `D` but *not* rows `B` or `C` (or `A`).

I have a larger range of columns than given in that toy example, so selecting a set of columns with, e.g., `&&` could make for a long command.

N.B., a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63881390/how-can-i-filter-rows-that-are-all-na-using-dplyr-across-syntax) addresses selecting rows where *none* are `NA`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::if_all`. You can select the columns very flexibly with [`tidyselect`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html), for instance using `:`, `c`, `starts_with`...

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(if_all(V1:V2, is.na))

#  D1 D2 V1 V2
#1  D  1 NA NA
```

Also works (this shows the flexibility of `tidyselect`):

```r
filter(df, if_all(3:4, is.na))
filter(df, if_all(starts_with("V"), is.na))
filter(df, if_all(c(V1, V2), is.na))
filter(df, if_all((last_col()-1):last_col(), is.na))
filter(df, if_all(num_range("V", 1:2), is.na))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
df %>% filter(is.na(V1) & is.na(V2))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  D1 D2 V1 V2
1  D  1 NA NA
```

Comment: Thank you (+1). Any ideas on selecting a range of columns as opposed to each column via `&`?