# R - keep rows with at least two non-missing values (tidyverse)

Tags: r, tidyverse

Assume you have any type of dataframe. How would you reduce it only to rows that have at least two non-missing values (in other words, how would you omit all rows that have three or more missing values) in a tidyverse manner so that it can be passed through pipes?

Comment: You can modify the third code block of the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame/4862502#4862502) (`<= 2` rather than `== 0`)

Comment: How to use that in a pipe? final %>%

Comment: The equivalent of `df[somevec,]` in dplyr is `df %>% filter(somevec)`