# Convert all empty & fields marked with "N/A" as NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to Machine Learning & R, so my question is a pretty basic one:

I have imported a dataset and performed some modifications and stored the final output in a dataframe named df_final.

Now I would like to replace all the empty fields and fields with "N/A", "n/a" as NA, so that I could use the inbuilt na libraries in R.

Any help in this context would be highly appreciated.

Cheers!
Vivek

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame

Comment: Check the above link

Comment: How were empty fields, "N/A", and "n/a" generated? If they are strings in the original data before you imported, you can deal with them by assigning `na.strings = c("", "N/A", "n/a")` in `read.table`.

Comment: Agree with @DarrenTsai: This should be solved during data import not afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the problem is best solved at read-in, by setting `na.strings = c("", "N/A", "n/a")` in `read.table`, as suggested by @Darren Tsai. If that's no longer an option because you've processed the data already **and**, as I suspect, you do *not* want to keep only complete cases, as suggested by @Rui Barradas, then the issue can be addressed this way:

**DATA**:

```
df_final <- data.frame(v1 = c(1, "N/A", 2, "n/a", "", 3),
                       v2 = c("a", "", "b", "c", "d", "N/A"))
df_final
   v1  v2
1   1   a
2 N/A    
3   2   b
4 n/a   c
5       d
6   3 N/A
```

**SOLUTION**:

To introduce `NA` into empty fields, you can do:

```
df_final[df_final==""] <- NA
df_final
    v1   v2
1    1    a
2  N/A <NA>
3    2    b
4  n/a    c
5 <NA>    d
6    3  N/A
```

To change the other values into `NA`, you can use `lapply` and a function:

```
df_final[,1:2] <- lapply(df_final[,1:2], function(x) gsub("N/A|n/a", NA, x))
df_final
    v1   v2
1    1    a
2 <NA> <NA>
3    2    b
4 <NA>    c
5 <NA>    d
6    3 <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a two steps solution.

1. Replace the bad values by real `NA` values.
2. Keep the `complete.cases`.

In base R:

```
is.na(df1) <- sapply(df1, function(x) x %in% c("", "N/A", "n/a"))
df_final <- df1[complete.cases(df1), , drop = FALSE]
df_final
#  x y
#1 a u
#3 d v
```

**Data creation code.**

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("a", "N/A", "d", "n/a", ""),
                  y = c("u", "", "v", "x", "y"))
```