# r data formatting with NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have a dataset with three columns like this below

```
 Id    Date       Gender
 1     NA         F
 1     NA         NA
 1     03-11-1977 NA
 2     04-17-2005 NA
 2     NA         M
 3     NA         NA 
 3     06-04-1999 NA
 3     NA         F
```

How could I clean this data such that I see a dataset like this below ?

```
Id    Date        Gender
 1     03-11-1977 F
 2     04-17-2005 M
 3     06-04-1999 F
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove rows with all or some NAs (missing values) in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame)

Comment: @Gnin Probably not, OP's data is grouped by `Id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fill` the values by `Id` and `filter` `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  tidyr::fill(Gender, .direction = "updown") %>%
  filter(!is.na(Date))

#     Id Date       Gender
#  <int> <chr>      <chr> 
#1     1 03-11-1977 F     
#2     2 04-17-2005 M     
#3     3 06-04-1999 F
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `na.omit` in a `by` approach.

```
dat <- do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$Id, function(x) cbind(x[1,1,drop=F], lapply(x[-1], na.omit))))
dat
#   Id       Date Gender
# 1  1 03-11-1977      F
# 2  2 04-17-2005      M
# 3  3 06-04-1999      F
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(header=T,text=' Id    Date       Gender
 1     NA         F
 1     NA         NA
 1     03-11-1977 NA
 2     04-17-2005 NA
 2     NA         M
 3     NA         NA 
 3     06-04-1999 NA
 3     NA         F')
```

Comment: @KimJenkins Which error? Could you be more specific? ;)