# Skip/delete rows having empty cells

Tags: r, shiny

I am uploading reading a text file in my shiny app.
Here is how I am reading it in shiny app:

```
data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    df <- read.table(file=input$file$datapath[input$file$name==input$Select], skip = 15, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'X Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[1])
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Y Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2])
    return(df)
  })
```

Now, I want to delete/skip the rows in the uploaded dataset having empty cells.

My attempt:

```
df[!apply(df == "", 1, all),]
```

But, it is not working.

Is there a different way to do it when using `read.table`?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame) post answers your question.

Comment: If your file is a single column, then you could try `read.table(..., blank.lines.skip=TRUE)` ... which is its default, suggesting that your data has more than one column. In that case, the answer is **No**, you need to do it post-`read.table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@maydin's link works great for `NA` values, but you'll need a little bit more to check for a specific *value* (i.e, `""`, the empty string).

```r
df <- data.frame(a=c('a','b',''), b="")
rowSums(df != "") == 0
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

That tells you which rows have exactly 0 non-empty strings on the row. If even one of the columns has something more than zero-length-string, then it'll pop as false.

Using this, we'll look for only rows with 1 or more non-empty-strings.

```r
df[rowSums(df != "") > 0, ]
#   a b
# 1 a  
# 2 b
```

Comment: I did not completly understand your answer. How can I use  'df[rowSums(df != "") > 0, ]' in read.table ?

Comment: As I said in my first comment, you cannot. What you're asking of `read.table` is to conditionally exclude rows based on individual cell contents. The arguments in `read.table` that allow omitting rows: `nrows`, `skip`, `blank.lines.skip`, `comment.char`, and possibly `skipNul`. None of those allow the logic of *"if a **column** is blank then skip the **row**"*. Anything on that scale needs to be done either before or after `read.table`.

Comment: Ok, understood.

Comment: I tried usind 'df[rowSums(df != "") > 0, ]' and 'df[!apply(df == "", 0, all), ]' after read.table. Both are not working.

Comment: Did you get it to work, kolas0202? (I see you accepted it since that comment.) If it doesn't work, it might be for several things, including not-quite-empty strings, `NA`s, or other logic that might dissuade `rowSums` from doing its job. If you need more help please include sample data (via `dput(head(x))`). Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer:

Here is the code:
Raw Data:

```
data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    df <- read.table(file=input$file$datapath[input$file$name==input$Select], skip = 15, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors, skipNul = TRUE, na.strings = "")
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'X Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[1])
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Y Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2])
    return(df)
  })
```

Data with removing the rows with empty cells:

```
data_1 <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    x <- data()[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
    x[x == ""] <- NA
    M <- na.omit(x)
    return(M)
  })
```