# Deleting rows with missing data. How to omit rows from a data frame with missing values in either column

Tags: r, missing-data

I want to create a new data frame that omits missing data.
My data is 2 independent people giving a score of an event from 1 to 5.

I want to omit any row with missing data from either rater 1 or rater 2 to create a data frame with only scores from both raters.

So that this data frame:

```
DF <- data.frame("rater 1"=c(1,4,NA,3,2), "rater 2"=c(1,NA,3,2,3))
head(DF)
```

Looks like this:

```
DF_omit <- data.frame("rater1"=c(1,3,2), "rater 2"=c(1,2,3))
head(DF_omit)
```

(ie row 2 and row 3 of DF have been omitted because of missing data from either rater 1 or rater 2)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few good ways of doing this - which have been well described elsewhere on SO (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame)). However, to use your example here:

I think `na.omit` is probably the simplest option for your purpose:

```
na.omit(DF)

#   rater.1 rater.2
# 1       1       1
# 4       3       2
# 5       2       3
```

There's also `complete.cases` which is a bit longer but allows you to restrict the NA search to specific columns. While this wasn't required in this question, for completeness it might help to know. For example if you only wanted to remove rows with `NA` in `rater.1`:

```
DF[complete.cases(DF$rater.1),]

#   rater.1 rater.2
# 1       1       1
# 2       4      NA
# 4       3       2
# 5       2       3
```

Also `tidyr` has `drop_na` which might be the easiest if you're already operating in the `tidyverse` and also has the same benefit as using `complete.cases`:

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% tidyr::drop_na(rater.1)

#   rater.1 rater.2
# 1       1       1
# 2       4      NA
# 3       3       2
# 4       2       3
```

Comment: than you much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use `complete.cases` to create a logical vector, then index the rows of DF using this vector:

`DF_omit <- DF[complete.cases(DF), ]`

Answer (score 0):

This is it?

```
DFnew <- na.omit(DF)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all rows with NAs from all columns:

```
Dataset <- df[complete.cases(df[,]),]
```

Remove all rows with NA's from specific columns:

```
Dataset <- df[complete.cases(df[,"column.name"]),] # column names that you want to drop NA's
```

Comment: Please accept one of the answers to close the issue. Thank you.