# Trailing zeros in kable

Tags: r, dataframe, format, knitr

Let's consider this simple data frame produced by kable function:

```
library(knitr)

df <- data.frame("X_1" = c(0.9131357, 0.9022396), "X_2" = c(6.328998e-07, 1.607509e-07))
kable(df, format = "pipe", digits = 3)

|   X_1| X_2|
|-----:|---:|
| 0.913|   0|
| 0.902|   0|
```

My question is - is there any possibility to add trailing zeroes to X_2 ? i.e. to have 0.000 instead of just 0 - it looks much better in my opinion when decimal places are equal for each column.

Comment: Did you try format()?

Comment: Using `kable(format(df, digits = 3))` you mean ?

Comment: I've found `sprintf()` helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178

Comment: Sry, I meant formatC() with the argument format = "f".

Answer (score 0):

it's not very elegant, but this works for me:

```
df2 <- data.frame(X_1=df$X_1, X_2=sprintf("%.03f", df$X_2))
kable(df2, format = "pipe", digits = 3, align="r")
```

```
|   X_1|   X_2|
|-----:|-----:|
| 0.913| 0.000|
| 0.902| 0.000|
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format.args` (see [kable documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html#format-numeric-columns) as well as `?format`), specifically the `nsmall` option:

```
> library(knitr)
> df <- data.frame("X_1" = c(0.9131357, 0.9022396), "X_2" = c(6.328998e-07, 1.607509e-07))
> kable(df, format = "pipe", digits = 3, format.args = list(nsmall = 3))

|   X_1|   X_2|
|-----:|-----:|
| 0.913| 0.000|
| 0.902| 0.000
```

`digits = 3` ensures that at most 3 decimal places are used, and `nsmall = 3` ensures at at least 3 decimal places are used. With both of these together you get the desired result.