# Remove row if NA in BOTH columns

Tags: r

I am trying to remove rows that have NA values in both Column 7 and Column 12.

I have found the complete.cases command for continuous features [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame):

```
dataframe[complete.cases(dataframe[ , 5:6]),]
```

I have tried the following variations and got the associated errors:

```
dataframe[complete.cases(dataframe[ , 7,12]),]
invalid 'type' (list) of argument

dataframe[complete.cases(dataframe[ , c(7,12)]),]
Error in C(7, 12) : object not interpretable as a factor

dataframe[complete.cases(dataframe[ , 7 & 12]),]
invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

I'm pretty sure I'm just messing up some basic syntax but I'm a bit new to this and drawing a blank. Key aspect, is that it needs to have NA in both column; e.g., if it has data in 7, but NA in 12 or vica versa, I want to keep it.

Comment: Hello @tchoup, do you want a base R answer or can I give you a tidyverse answer?

Comment: The second error message shows a capital `C` call, are you sure you ran the code as you pasted it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(!if_all(everything(), ~ is.na(.x)))

  x  y
1 1 NA
2 2  2
3 4  5
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(x = c(1, 2, NA, 4), y = c(NA, 2, NA, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

You might as well assign your desired columns to `.cols` argument. Here in my sample example I chose `everything()`.