# Delete rows where column is NA

Tags: r, dataframe

What's the best formula to delete rows where an row has NA value?

will this work?

```
all_trips_v2 <- all_trips_v2 %>% 
  filter(!(ride_length = "NA"))
```

Want to delete all rows where ride_length = NA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove rows with all or some NAs (missing values) in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `filter` should be...

```
new_df <- all_trips_v2 %>%
   filter(!is.na(ride_length))
```

EDIT: A `filter` doesn't necessarily 'delete' rows.  Also, "NA" in quotes, a character string, is not the same as an *NA* as in...no value.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the paranthesis around "NA", otherwise you will match the character pattern "NA" not actual NAs. You may look at the functions na.omit(), complete.cases() or **is.na()** - so something like filter(!is.na(ridge_length))