# Removing NA’s from a dataset in R

Tags: r, na

I want to remove all of the NA’s from the variables selected however when I used `na.omited()` for example:

```
na.omit(df$livharm)
```

it does not work and the NA’s are still there. I have also tried an alternative way for example:

```
married[is.na(livharm1)] <-NA
```

I have done this for each variable within the larger variable I am looking at using the code:
E.g.

```
df <- within(df, { 
married <- as.numeric(livharm == 1) 
“
“
“ 

married[is.na(livharm1)] <- NA

})
```

however I’m not sure what I actually have to do. Any help I would greatly appreciate!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove rows with all or some NAs (missing values) in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame)

Comment: Hi, I’ve tried these however it runs the code correctly yet when I go to use ggplot it still shows the NA results within the graph as well as still showing them within a table when the summary command in r studio. Thank you for coming back to me :)

Comment: Are you sure that your NA values are really NA? They may also be character or factor.

Comment: @Anonymous_tech can you please share your data by pasting the output of ``dput(data)`` into your original question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you!! :))

Answer (score 1):

Using `complete.cases` gives:

```
dat <- data.frame( a=c(1,2,3,4,5),b=c(1,NA,3,4,5) )

dat
  a  b
1 1  1
2 2 NA
3 3  3
4 4  4
5 5  5

complete.cases(dat)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

# is.na equivalent has to be used on a vector for the same result:
!is.na(dat$b)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

dat[complete.cases(dat),]
  a b
1 1 1
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
```

Using `na.omit` is the same as `complete.cases` but instead of returning a boolean vector the object itself is returned.

```
na.omit(dat)
  a b
1 1 1
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
```

This function returns a different result when applied only to a vector, which is probably not handled correctly by `ggplot2`. It can be "rescued" by putting it back in a data frame. **base** `plot` works as intended though.

```
na.omit(dat$b)
[1] 1 3 4 5
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 2
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"

data.frame(b=na.omit(dat$b))
  b
1 1
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

Plotting with `ggplot2`

```
ggplot(dat[complete.cases(dat),]) + geom_point( aes(a,b) )
# <plot>

# See warning when using original data set with NAs
ggplot(dat) + geom_point( aes(a,b) )
Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
# <same plot as above>
```

Comment: Thats great thank you!! :))