# How to remove NA and Blank rows in R Programming

Tags: r

How do I remove the NAs and blanks in one go (from DATE to BODYPAIN)?[image: See the Attach image]

[image: I want this Output in R programming]

Comment: first convert `""` to `NA`, then use `complete.cases()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove rows with all or some NAs (missing values) in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame)

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including the code you tried and a snippet of your data or some fake data, rather than an image of the data. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).