# Drop rows with NA in multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, na

There are various questions on dropping rows containing NA with `drop_na()`, but I haven't found one that addresses my particular need. I would like to drop rows that contain NA in every one of 3 specific columns. In this case, drop rows that contain NA in `value2` AND `value3` AND `value4`, but not drop rows that contain NA in fewer than all three, or in any other columns.

```
sample <- c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4", "sample5")
value1<- c("A", "B", "A", NA, "C")
value2 <- c(NA, 5, 7, NA, NA)
value3 <- c(13, NA, 7, NA, NA)
value4 <- c(11, 4, NA, 9, NA)
myinput <- data.frame(sample, value1, value2, value3, value4)

myinput
   sample value1 value2 value3 value4
1 sample1      A     NA     13     11
2 sample2      B      5     NA      4
3 sample3      A      7      7     NA
4 sample4     NA     NA     NA      9
5 sample5      C     NA     NA     NA
```

Desired output:

```
   sample value1 value2 value3 value4
1 sample1      A     NA     13     11
2 sample2      B      5     NA      4
3 sample3      A      7      7     NA
4 sample4     NA     NA     NA      9
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way with `collapse::na_omit`:

```r
collapse::na_omit(myinput, cols = paste0("value", 2:4), prop = 1)

#>    sample value1 value2 value3 value4
#> 1 sample1      A     NA     13     11
#> 2 sample2      B      5     NA      4
#> 3 sample3      A      7      7     NA
#> 4 sample4   <NA>     NA     NA      9
```

---

**Benchmark on a 1,000,000 x 21 data set:**

`collapse` is 5x-6x faster:

```r
#Using data from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48830183/13460602
library(dplyr)
library(collapse)

mb <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rowSums = df[rowSums(is.na(df[, 2:21])) < 3,],
  "dplyr+rowSums" = df %>%
    filter(rowSums(is.na(pick(2:21))) < 3),
  if_all = df |>
    filter(!if_all(2:21, is.na)),
  collapse = na_omit(df, cols = 2:21, prop = 1)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We can use `is.na` and `rowSums` to count the number of `NA`s in each row.

## base R

```r
myinput[rowSums(is.na(myinput[, c("value2", "value3", "value4")])) < 3,]
#    sample value1 value2 value3 value4
# 1 sample1      A     NA     13     11
# 2 sample2      B      5     NA      4
# 3 sample3      A      7      7     NA
# 4 sample4   <NA>     NA     NA      9
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
myinput %>%
  filter(rowSums(is.na(pick(value1, value2, value3))) < 3)
#    sample value1 value2 value3 value4
# 1 sample1      A     NA     13     11
# 2 sample2      B      5     NA      4
# 3 sample3      A      7      7     NA
# 4 sample5      C     NA     NA     NA
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr::if_all` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

myinput |>
  filter(!if_all(value2:value4, is.na))
#>    sample value1 value2 value3 value4
#> 1 sample1      A     NA     13     11
#> 2 sample2      B      5     NA      4
#> 3 sample3      A      7      7     NA
#> 4 sample4   <NA>     NA     NA      9
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Using `across` in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)

myinput %>% 
  filter(rowSums(across(value2:value4, ~ is.na(.x))) < 3)
   sample value1 value2 value3 value4
1 sample1      A     NA     13     11
2 sample2      B      5     NA      4
3 sample3      A      7      7     NA
4 sample4   <NA>     NA     NA      9
```