# How to exclude all rows from a calculation just because another variable has NA

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, na

**Problem description: I would like to apply a formula excluding all rows that contain at least one NA value. For reproducible examples I have used the following data frame:**

```
df <- data.frame(
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                check.names = FALSE,
                       Date = c("01/11/1876",
                                "01/12/1876","01/01/1877","01/02/1877",
                                "01/03/1877","01/04/1877","01/05/1877",
                                "01/06/1877","01/07/1877","01/08/1877","01/09/1877",
                                "01/10/1877","01/11/1877","01/12/1877",
                                "01/01/1878","01/02/1878"),
        `Bissen P [mm]` = c(59.2,139.4,
                                89.6,46.9,41.1,105.1,45.3,62.3,NA,119.1,
                                121.2,86.1,42.1,54,37.3,71.8),
        `Bissen Q [mm]` = c(46.5,126.5,
                                111.7,53.9,49.4,28.1,31.9,22.3,19.1,24.9,
                                74.1,74.1,51.8,47.3,40.8,53.4),
    `Ettel P [mm]` = c(54,131.3,
                                83.3,42.1,NA,98.3,40.6,56.9,44.7,111.8,
                                113.8,79.9,37.5,49,32.8,66.1),
      `Ettel Q [mm]` = c(29.9,84.1,
                                77.9,39.9,35.1,21.7,24.4,15.7,14.5,20.1,
                                51.1,58.6,36,41.8,32.7,37.7),
           `Aalbach P [mm]` = c(46.6,112.7,
                                71.7,36.5,31.7,84.4,35.2,49.1,38.7,96,
                                97.7,68.7,32.6,42.3,28.5,57),
           `Aalbach Q [mm]` = c(59.8,132.4,
                                87.3,48.7,43.4,101.4,47.2,62.6,51.1,114.1,
                                116,84.1,44.3,55.1,39.9,71.2))

#Where I have 3 sites (Bissen, Ettel and Aalbach) and each site has 2 variables (P and Q)
#And I would like to obtain the runoff coefficient of each site (Q/P),
```

In yellow rectangles I have indicated which rows must be excluded per site since one row contains a NA.

[image]

```
 
#step 2: extract site names
site_names <- sub(" P \\[mm\\]| Q \\[mm\\]", "", names(df)[-1]) |>
  unique()
site_names

#step 3: define function based on formula: 
#Here I have indicated that NA should be excluded, however, it does not eliminate all rows as I need. 
formula <- function(P, Q) {
  runoffcoefficient = mean(Q, na.rm = TRUE)/mean(P, na.rm = TRUE)
  return(data.frame(runoffcoefficient = runoffcoefficient))
}

# step 4: Loop through all sites
results <- list()
for (site in site_names) {
  site_data <- df[, grepl(site, names(df))]
  coefficients <- formula(site_data[[paste0(site, " P [mm]")]], 
                         site_data[[paste0(site, " Q [mm]")]]) 
  df$Site = site # Add the Site column to each site's anomalies
  results[[site]] <- coefficients
}  

> results  
$Bissen
  runoffcoefficient
1         0.7160308

$Ettel
  runoffcoefficient
1         0.5588475

$Aalbach
  runoffcoefficient
1          1.246611
```

**If rows where eliminated, Bissen would be equal to 0.7467, and Ettel = 0.5624**

**Any help would be truly appreciated**

Comment: Does the following answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: When you say "exclude values *per site*" do you mean that, for instance, you need to exclude row 5 *only for Ettel site* or for all sites?

Comment: Only for Ettel in this case.

Comment: My expected output would be : Aalbach = 1.2466107,    Bissen = 0.7467202 and Ettel = 0.5624220.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was able to answer was by modifying step 3 as follows:

```
#step 3: define function based on formula: 
#Here I have indicated that NA should be excluded, however, it does not eliminate all rows as I need. 
formula <- function(P, Q) {
  # Subset rows with non-missing values for both P and Q
  complete_rows <- !is.na(P) & !is.na(Q)
  P_complete <- P[complete_rows]
  Q_complete <- Q[complete_rows]
  runoffcoefficient = mean(Q_complete, na.rm = TRUE)/mean(P_complete, na.rm = TRUE)
  return(data.frame(runoffcoefficient = runoffcoefficient))
}
```

or when I would like to indicate that either P or Q has a NA value, the other must be excluded as well, `complete.cases` can be used as follows:

```
formula <- function(P, Q) {
  # Subset rows with non-missing values for both P and Q
  complete_rows <- complete.cases(P, Q)
  P_complete <- P[complete_rows]
  Q_complete <- Q[complete_rows]
  # Calculate runoff coefficient using complete rows only
  runoffcoefficient <- mean(Q_complete)/mean(P_complete)
  return(data.frame(runoffcoefficient = runoffcoefficient))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to exclude row 5 only in the calculation of Ettel site (and similarly row 9 for Bissen) while saving values in other sites, your problem is one of simply storing the data differently. Reshape into a long format by:

```
dflong <- reshape(
  df, 
  direction='long', 
  idvar='Date', 
  varying=list(c(2,4,6), c(3,5,7)), 
  v.names=c('P', 'Q'), 
  times=c('Bissen', 'Ettel', 'Aalbach'),
  timevar='Site'
)
```

and then you can restrict to complete cases (`dflong[complete.cases(dflong), ]` or use `na.omit`), and then loop calculations across the "Site" variable using `tapply` as needed.

```
> with(na.omit(dflong), tapply(Q, Site, mean) / tapply(P, Site, mean))
   Albach    Bissen     Ettel 
1.2466107 0.7467202 0.5624220
```

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming P and Q columns are in the shown order, using `lapply` you could subset on the city names, create a temporary data frame while applying `na.omit` and calculate your function. This will exclude `NA`s for each city individually and not for the entire data frame.

```
> cols <- unique(sub(r'{\s[PQ]\s\[mm\]}', '', names(df)[-1]))
> lapply(setNames(cols, cols), \(x) {
+      tmp <- na.omit(df[grep(x, names(df))])
+      mean(tmp[[2]])/mean(tmp[[1]])
+    })
$Bissen
[1] 0.7467202

$Ettel
[1] 0.562422

$Aalbach
[1] 1.246611
```

NB: don't use `formula` or any other name that is already used to name an object, this is very confusing and considered bad practice. Always check e.g. `?formula` if it's already used.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Date = c("01/11/1876", "01/12/1876", "01/01/1877", 
"01/02/1877", "01/03/1877", "01/04/1877", "01/05/1877", "01/06/1877", 
"01/07/1877", "01/08/1877", "01/09/1877", "01/10/1877", "01/11/1877", 
"01/12/1877", "01/01/1878", "01/02/1878"), `Bissen P [mm]` = c(59.2, 
139.4, 89.6, 46.9, 41.1, 105.1, 45.3, 62.3, NA, 119.1, 121.2, 
86.1, 42.1, 54, 37.3, 71.8), `Bissen Q [mm]` = c(46.5, 126.5, 
111.7, 53.9, 49.4, 28.1, 31.9, 22.3, 19.1, 24.9, 74.1, 74.1, 
51.8, 47.3, 40.8, 53.4), `Ettel P [mm]` = c(54, 131.3, 83.3, 
42.1, NA, 98.3, 40.6, 56.9, 44.7, 111.8, 113.8, 79.9, 37.5, 49, 
32.8, 66.1), `Ettel Q [mm]` = c(29.9, 84.1, 77.9, 39.9, 35.1, 
21.7, 24.4, 15.7, 14.5, 20.1, 51.1, 58.6, 36, 41.8, 32.7, 37.7
), `Aalbach P [mm]` = c(46.6, 112.7, 71.7, 36.5, 31.7, 84.4, 
35.2, 49.1, 38.7, 96, 97.7, 68.7, 32.6, 42.3, 28.5, 57), `Aalbach Q [mm]` = c(59.8, 
132.4, 87.3, 48.7, 43.4, 101.4, 47.2, 62.6, 51.1, 114.1, 116, 
84.1, 44.3, 55.1, 39.9, 71.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct except the ratios are inverted.

Comment: @AdamO Maybe you're right, I've changed that. However OP switches order of P and Q, not sure what they really want.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
site_names <- sub(" P \\[mm\\]| Q \\[mm\\]", "", names(df)[-1])

fn <- function(x){
  y <- colMeans(na.omit(x))
  y[[2]]/y[[1]]
}
sapply(split.default(df[-1], site_names), fn)


  Aalbach    Bissen     Ettel 
1.2466107 0.7467202 0.5624220
```